# Override Native Javascript Constructor

Tags: javascript, date, overriding

I want to override javascript Date. Aim is to get time 1 hour prior to the current time. But if arguments are passed to the Date function, it should behave in a default way. Is there any way to achieve this ? (should work on IE11 as well)

I have tried something like this but it fails for certain arguments.

```
Date = function(options) {

Date.prototype = x.prototype;
if(options)
    return new x(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join())
else
    return new x(x.now()-(1000*60*60))
```

}

Comment: Could you explain why you need this?

Comment: @t.niese in some cases I have custom delay setup in my product. Currently we have used new Date() everywhere. So I need to override it completely so that code in the product is not affected.

Comment: That is a perfect way to make your code base completely unmanageable. Don't do this.

Comment: @trincot can you suggest some way to solve my use case without overriding it ?

Comment: For that you have to really explain and convince us of the deeper problem you try to solve.

Comment: You should fix the code in your code base. Messing around with the default behavior of build in types is a really bad idea.

Comment: @trincot so explaining the usecase will be a bit difficult over here. To give an overview of what i am trying to achieve, we have certain functionality which is giving us the delay time. The delay time remains constant for a particular session. Using that delay we need to show the time {delay} time before the current time. Something like Date.now()-delay .

Comment: @t.niese Can the above use case be solved without messing with the default behavior?

Comment: I think your biggest issue is how to call the Date constructor with multiple arguments in the case where they're provided **and** support IE 11. If that wasn't a constraint, you could do `if (arguments.length) return new oDate(...agruments)`, but in the absence of destructuring you need something like this: [*How can I construct an object using an array of values for parameters, rather than listing them out, in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813383/how-can-i-construct-an-object-using-an-array-of-values-for-parameters-rather-th)