# How to get a JavaScript object's class?

Tags: javascript, oop

I created a JavaScript object, but how I can determine the class of that object?

I want something similar to Java's `.getClass()` method.

Comment: for example , I make a Person like this :

var p = new Person();

I have a Person Object that called "p", how can I use "p" to get back the Class name: "Person".

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript)

Comment: Update: As of ECMAScript 6, JavaScript still doesn't have a `class` type. It **does** have a `class` keyword and `class` syntax for creating prototypes in which the methods can more easily access `super`.

Comment: What about Object.className?

Comment: @Paul-Basenko : "className" won't tell you the object's class, but will return the content of an HTML element's "class" property, which refers to CSS classes. You also want to use "classList" to manage them easily, but it's not related to the OP's question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the name of an object's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type)

Answer (score 1414, accepted):

There's no exact counterpart to Java's [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) in JavaScript. Mostly that's due to JavaScript being a [prototype-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), as opposed to Java being a [class-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) one.

Depending on what you need `getClass()` for, there are several options in JavaScript:

- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)
- `obj.`[`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)
- `func.`[`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype), `proto`.[`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)

A few examples:

```
function Foo() {}
var foo = new Foo();

typeof Foo;             // == "function"
typeof foo;             // == "object"

foo instanceof Foo;     // == true
foo.constructor.name;   // == "Foo"
Foo.name                // == "Foo"    

Foo.prototype.isPrototypeOf(foo);   // == true

Foo.prototype.bar = function (x) {return x+x;};
foo.bar(21);            // == 42
```

Note: if you are compiling your code with Uglify it will change non-global class names. To prevent this, Uglify has a [`--mangle`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) param that you can set to false is using [gulp](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify) or [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).

Comment: That should probably be `func.prototype` (yes, functions are objects, but the `prototype` property is only relevant on function objects).

Comment: you might also want to mention `instanceof`/`isPrototypeOf()` and the non-standard `__proto__`

Comment: ES5 has aditionally `Object.getPrototypeOf()`

Comment: For me, foo.constructor yields something different (Chrome 8.0.552.0 dev on Mac OS X): `Function Foo() {}`

Comment: Yes, clarkf, that's `Foo` pretty-printed. The comments don't indicate the return values, but equalities that hold for the return values. So the comment means that `foo.constructor == Foo` holds, which will also be the case for you.

Comment: another one to add: in a technical sense, the way to get the `class` of an object is with `Object.prototype.toString.call(myObject)`. What this question is really about is getting the constructor and/or prototype, not the class, but it may be worth adding this for completeness. [See this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString()_to_detect_object_class)

Comment: I use `new this.constructor()` to instantiate new instance of the current Object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor

Comment: **Warning**: don't rely on `constructor.name` if your code is being minified. The function name is going to change arbitrarily.

Comment: if your class inherits from another, this.constructor will be the parent one.

Comment: You should add this case: `var Foo = () => true;` It's returning `function` whenever you call `console.log(typeof Foo)`. `Foo` is a function but a constructor.

Comment: @igorsantos07, at least in 2019; the top 5-10 google results for "online javascript minifier" recognize `construction.name` as a token to be ignored / not minimize. Besides most (if not all) minifier software provide exception rules.

Answer (score 441):

```
obj.constructor.name
```

is a reliable method in modern browsers. `Function.name` was officially added to the standard in ES6, making this a standards-compliant means of getting the class of a JavaScript object as a string. If the object is instantiated with `var obj = new MyClass()`, it will return "MyClass".

It will return "Number" for numbers, "Array" for arrays and "Function" for functions, etc. It generally behaves as expected. The only cases where it fails are if an object is created without a prototype, via `Object.create( null )`, or the object was instantiated from an anonymously-defined (unnamed) function.

Also note that if you are minifying your code, it's not safe to compare against hard-coded type strings. For example instead of checking if `obj.constructor.name == "MyType"`, instead check `obj.constructor.name == MyType.name`. Or just compare the constructors themselves, however this won't work across DOM boundaries as there are different instances of the constructor function on each DOM.

Comment: `Function.name` is not (yet) part of the JavaScript standard. It is currently supported in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE(10).

Comment: `Object.create(something).constructor === something.constructor`, which is not quite correct too. So obj.constructor is unreliable for all objects made with Object.create, no matter with or without a prototype.

Comment: **Warning**: don't rely on `constructor.name` if your code is being minified. The function name is going to change arbitrarily.

Comment: Function.name is part of ES6, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: @devios1
I don't understand your note about chaining prototypes.
For me it works correctly (tested on Firefox console):
`class A { };
class B extends A { };
b = new B();
b.constructor.name;
"B"
`

Comment: @adalbertpl It had to do with manually chaining prototypes, before ES6. It's good to know `constructor.name` behaves as expected with the new class support in ES6.

Answer (score 40):

This `getNativeClass()` function returns `undefined` for undefined values and `null` for null.
For all other values, the `CLASSNAME`-part is extracted from `[object CLASSNAME]`, which is the result of using `Object.prototype.toString.call(value)`.

`getAnyClass()` behaves the same as `getNativeClass()`, but also supports custom constructors:

```js
function getNativeClass(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "undefined") return "undefined";
  if (obj === null) return "null";
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1];
}

function getAnyClass(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "undefined") return "undefined";
  if (obj === null) return "null";
  return obj.constructor.name;
}

getNativeClass("")   === "String";
getNativeClass(true) === "Boolean";
getNativeClass(0)    === "Number";
getNativeClass([])   === "Array";
getNativeClass({})   === "Object";
getNativeClass(null) === "null";

getAnyClass(new (function Foo(){})) === "Foo";
getAnyClass(new class Foo{}) === "Foo";

// etc...
```

Comment: Object.prototype.getClass = function(){ using 'this' instead of obj would be nice

Comment: of course then null and undefined would be uncheckable since only the Object would have the getClass method

Comment: This only works on native objects. If you have some kind of inheritance going you will always get `"Object"`.

Comment: Yeah, the last line of the function should just be `return obj.constructor.name`. That gives the same results, plus also handles non native objects.

Answer (score 33):

We can read Class's name of an instance by just doing 'instance.constructor.name' like in this example:

```
class Person {
  type = "developer";
}
let p = new Person();

p.constructor.name // Person
```

Comment: all fun until you minify your JS and your class name is now `n`
JS really blows for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 22):

To get the "pseudo class", you can get the constructor function, by

```
obj.constructor
```

assuming the `constructor` is set correctly when you do the inheritance -- which is by something like:

```
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
```

and these two lines, together with:

```
var woofie = new Dog()
```

will make `woofie.constructor` point to `Dog`.  Note that `Dog` is a constructor function, and is a `Function` object.  But you can do `if (woofie.constructor === Dog) { ... }`.

If you want to get the class name as a string, I found the following working well:

http://blog.magnetiq.com/post/514962277/finding-out-class-names-of-javascript-objects

```
function getObjectClass(obj) {
    if (obj && obj.constructor && obj.constructor.toString) {
        var arr = obj.constructor.toString().match(
            /function\s*(\w+)/);

        if (arr && arr.length == 2) {
            return arr[1];
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

It gets to the constructor function, converts it to string, and extracts the name of the constructor function.

Note that `obj.constructor.name` could have worked well, but it is not standard.  It is on Chrome and Firefox, but not on IE, including IE 9 or IE 10 RTM.

Comment: You get points for woofie.

Answer (score 16):

You can get a reference to the constructor function which created the object by using the [constructor property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

```
function MyObject(){
}

var obj = new MyObject();
obj.constructor; // MyObject
```

If you need to confirm the type of an object at runtime you can use the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator) operator:

```
obj instanceof MyObject // true
```

Comment: doesn't it return the constructor function itself, like, you can call it again and create a new object of that type?

Comment: @SparK Yes, though you can still use this for a comparison so long as you are on the same DOM (you are comparing function objects). However it is much better practice to turn the constructor into a string and compare that, specifically because it works across DOM boundaries when using iframes.

Comment: This answer returns the "class" (or at least a handle the object which can be used to create an instance of the class - which is the same as "the class"). The above answers all returned strings which is not the same as "the class object" (as it were).

Answer (score 11):

i had a situation to work generic now and used this:

```
class Test {
  // your class definition
}

nameByType = function(type){
  return type.prototype["constructor"]["name"];
};

console.log(nameByType(Test));
```

thats the only way i found to get the class name by type input if you don't have a instance of an object.

(written in ES2017)

dot notation also works fine

```
console.log(Test.prototype.constructor.name); // returns "Test"
```

Comment: Ah this is what I was looking for. If it's not instantiated you have to use 'prototype' to get the class name. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 9):

In keeping with its unbroken record of backwards-compatibility, ECMAScript 6, JavaScript still doesn't have a `class` type (though not everyone understands this). It **does** have a `class` keyword as part of its `class` syntax for creating prototypes—but **still no thing called class**. JavaScript is not now and has **never been a classical OOP language**. Speaking of JS in terms of class is only either misleading or a sign of not yet grokking prototypical inheritance (just keeping it real).

That means `this.constructor` is still a great way to get a reference to the `constructor` function. And `this.constructor.prototype` is the way to access the prototype itself. Since this isn't Java, it's not a class. It's the prototype object your instance was instantiated from. Here is an example using the ES6 syntactic sugar for creating a prototype chain:

```
class Foo {
  get foo () {
    console.info(this.constructor, this.constructor.name)
    return 'foo'
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  get foo () {
    console.info('[THIS]', this.constructor, this.constructor.name, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.constructor.prototype))
    console.info('[SUPER]', super.constructor, super.constructor.name, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(super.constructor.prototype))

    return `${super.foo} + bar`
  }
}

const bar = new Bar()
console.dir(bar.foo)
```

This is what that outputs using `babel-node`:

```
> $ babel-node ./foo.js                                                                                                                   ⬡ 6.2.0 [±master ●]
[THIS] [Function: Bar] 'Bar' [ 'constructor', 'foo' ]
[SUPER] [Function: Foo] 'Foo' [ 'constructor', 'foo' ]
[Function: Bar] 'Bar'
'foo + bar'
```

There you have it! In 2016, there's a `class` keyword in JavaScript, but still no class type. `this.constructor` is the best way to get the constructor function, `this.constructor.prototype` the best way to get access to the prototype itself.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `o.constructor` because it can be changed by the object content. Instead, use `Object.getPrototypeOf()?.constructor`.

```js
const fakedArray = JSON.parse('{ "constructor": { "name": "Array" } }');

// returns 'Array', which is faked.
fakedArray.constructor.name;

// returns 'Object' as expected
Object.getPrototypeOf(fakedArray)?.constructor?.name;
```

Answer (score 6):

For Javascript Classes in ES6 you can use `object.constructor`. In the example class below the `getClass()` method returns the ES6 class as you would expect:

```
var Cat = class {

    meow() {

        console.log("meow!");

    }

    getClass() {

        return this.constructor;

    }

}

var fluffy = new Cat();

...

var AlsoCat = fluffy.getClass();
var ruffles = new AlsoCat();

ruffles.meow();    // "meow!"
```

If you instantiate the class from the `getClass` method make sure you wrap it in brackets e.g. `ruffles = new ( fluffy.getClass() )( args... );`

Answer (score 5):

If you need to not only GET class but also EXTEND it from having just an instance, write:

let's have

```
 class A{ 
   constructor(name){ 
     this.name = name
   }
 };

 const a1 = new A('hello a1');
```

so to extend A having the instance only use:

```
const a2 = new (Object.getPrototypeOf(a1)).constructor('hello from a2')
// the analog of const a2 = new A()

console.log(a2.name)//'hello from a2'
```

Answer (score 4):

## `getClass()` function using *constructor.prototype.name*

I found a way to access the `class` that is much cleaner than some of the solutions above; here it is.

```
function getClass(obj) {

   // if the type is not an object return the type
   if((let type = typeof obj) !== 'object') return type; 
    
   //otherwise, access the class using obj.constructor.name
   else return obj.constructor.name;   
}
```

### How it works

the constructor has a property called `name` accessing that will give you the class name.

cleaner version of the code:

```
function getClass(obj) {

   // if the type is not an object return the type
   let type = typeof obj
   if((type !== 'object')) { 
      return type; 
   } else { //otherwise, access the class using obj.constructor.name
      return obj.constructor.name; 
   }   
}
```

Comment: A comment from above: "Warning: don't rely on constructor.name if your code is being minified. The function name is going to change arbitrarily."

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, there are no classes, but I think that you want the constructor name and `obj.constructor.toString()` will tell you what you need.

Comment: This will return the entire definition of the constructor function as a string. What you really want is `.name`.

Comment: but `.name` is not defined even on IE 9

Answer (score 2):

I find `object.constructor.toString()` return `[object objectClass]` in IE ,rather than `function objectClass () {}` returned in chome. So,I think the code in http://blog.magnetiq.com/post/514962277/finding-out-class-names-of-javascript-objects may not work well in IE.And I fixed the code as follows:

#### code:

```
var getObjectClass = function (obj) {
        if (obj && obj.constructor && obj.constructor.toString()) {
            
                /*
                 *  for browsers which have name property in the constructor
                 *  of the object,such as chrome 
                 */
                if(obj.constructor.name) {
                    return obj.constructor.name;
                }
                var str = obj.constructor.toString();
                /*
                 * executed if the return of object.constructor.toString() is 
                 * "[object objectClass]"
                 */
                 
                if(str.charAt(0) == '[')
                {
                        var arr = str.match(/\[\w+\s*(\w+)\]/);
                } else {
                        /*
                         * executed if the return of object.constructor.toString() is 
                         * "function objectClass () {}"
                         * for IE Firefox
                         */
                        var arr = str.match(/function\s*(\w+)/);
                }
                if (arr && arr.length == 2) {
                            return arr[1];
                        }
          }
          return undefined; 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with dfa, that's why i consider the prototye as the class when no named class found

Here is an upgraded function of the one posted by Eli Grey, to match my way of mind

```
function what(obj){
    if(typeof(obj)==="undefined")return "undefined";
    if(obj===null)return "Null";
    var res = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1];
    if(res==="Object"){
        res = obj.constructor.name;
        if(typeof(res)!='string' || res.length==0){
            if(obj instanceof jQuery)return "jQuery";// jQuery build stranges Objects
            if(obj instanceof Array)return "Array";// Array prototype is very sneaky
            return "Object";
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here's a implementation of `getClass()` and `getInstance()`

You are able to get a reference for an Object's class using `this.constructor`.

### From an instance context:

```
function A() {
  this.getClass = function() {
    return this.constructor;
  }

  this.getNewInstance = function() {
    return new this.constructor;
  }
}

var a = new A();
console.log(a.getClass());  //  function A { // etc... }

// you can even:
var b = new (a.getClass());
console.log(b instanceof A); // true
var c = a.getNewInstance();
console.log(c instanceof A); // true
```

### From static context:

```
function A() {};

A.getClass = function() {
  return this;
}

A.getInstance() {
  return new this;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `this.constructor`?

Comment: I don't know, but if it is better, you can definitely edit the answer to improve it as you find better, after all this is a community.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this

```js
 class Hello {
     constructor(){
     }
    }
    
      function isClass (func) {
        return typeof func === 'function' && /^class\s/.test(Function.prototype.toString.call(func))
    }
    
   console.log(isClass(Hello))
```

This will tell you if the input is class or not

Comment: The above `isClass` implementation fails for e.g. `isClass(Array)`, `isClass(Object)`, ... Besides that, the OP didn't want to know whether a function is a class constructor but instead wants to get/access the class (which is the constructor function) reference of any given type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Object.prototype.constructor.name`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "getClass", {
    value: function() {
      return this.constructor.name;
    }
});

var x = new DOMParser();
console.log(x.getClass()); // `DOMParser'

var y = new Error("");
console.log(y.getClass()); // `Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class ICT{
   //your logic
}

const student= new ICT();

if (student instanceof ICT) {
  console.log('student is an instance of ICT');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to an instance of the class Foo (say foo = new Foo()) then there is exactly one way to get access to the the class from the instance: foo.Contructor in Javascript = foo.getClass() in Java.

eval() is another way, but since eval() is never recommended and works for everything (analogous to Java reflection), that answer is not recommended.  foo.Constructor = Foo

Comment: it looks like your answer got truncated. Please check and extend the answer or fix the last phrase.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript is a class-less languages: there are no classes that defines the behaviour of a class statically as in Java. JavaScript uses prototypes instead of classes for defining object properties, including methods, and inheritance. It is possible to simulate many class-based features with prototypes in JavaScript.

Comment: Update: As of ECMAScript 6, JavaScript still doesn't have a `class` type. It **does** have a `class` keyword and `class` syntax for creating prototypes in which the methods can more easily access `super`.

Answer (score -4):

Question seems already answered but the OP wants to access the class of and object, just like we do in Java and the selected answer is not enough (imho).

With the following explanation, we can get a class of an object(it's actually called prototype in javascript).

```
var arr = new Array('red', 'green', 'blue');
var arr2 = new Array('white', 'black', 'orange');
```

You can add a property like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(arr,'last', {
  get: function(){
    return this[this.length -1];
  }
});
console.log(arr.last) // blue
```

But `.last` property will only be available to '`arr`' object which is instantiated from Array prototype. So, in order to have the `.last` property to be available for all objects instantiated from Array prototype, we have to define the `.last` property for Array prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'last', {
  get: function(){
    return this[this.length -1];
  }
});
console.log(arr.last) // blue
console.log(arr2.last) // orange
```

The problem here is, you have to know which object type (prototype) the '`arr`' and '`arr2`' variables belongs to! In other words, if you don't know class type (prototype) of the '`arr`' object, then you won't be able to define a property for them. In the above example, we know arr is instance of the Array object, that's why we used Array.prototype to define a property for Array. But what if we didn't know the class(prototype) of the '`arr`'?

```
Object.defineProperty(arr.__proto__,'last2', {
  get: function(){
    return this[this.length -1];
  }
});
console.log(arr.last) // blue
console.log(arr2.last) // orange
```

As you can see, without knowing that '`arr`' is an Array, we can add a new property just bu referring the class of the '`arr`' by using '`arr.__proto__`'.

We accessed the prototype of the '`arr`' without knowing that it's an instance of Array and I think that's what OP asked.

Comment: The `__proto__` property is deprecated, and has almost no advantage over the `prototype` property.

Answer (score -4):

There is one another technique to identify your class
You can store ref to your class in instance like below.

```js
class MyClass {
    static myStaticProperty = 'default';
    constructor() {
        this.__class__ = new.target;
        this.showStaticProperty = function() {
            console.log(this.__class__.myStaticProperty);
        }
    }
}

class MyChildClass extends MyClass {
    static myStaticProperty = 'custom';
}

let myClass = new MyClass();
let child = new MyChildClass();

myClass.showStaticProperty(); // default
child.showStaticProperty(); // custom

myClass.__class__ === MyClass; // true
child.__class__ === MyClass; // false
child.__class__ === MyChildClass; // true
```