# Why does combination constructor/prototype pattern return typeof being object?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming

I'm having a hard time understanding why typeof doesn't return MyObject on an instance of MyObject when using this constructor/prototype pattern - it's returning object on an instance created by new using the MyObject constructor after the prototype for MyObject has had it's constructor set to MyObject - can someone explain why?

```
function MyObject(foo, bar) {
  this.foo = foo;
  this.bar = bar;
}

MyObject.prototype = {
  constructor: MyObject,
  someFunc: function() {
    console.log(foo + " and " + bar);
  }  
}

var newObject = new MyObject("a", "b");
typeof newObject;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `instanceof` operator if you want to check that: `newObject instanceof MyObject;` (returns true)

More info as to why typeof behaves like that: http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html

Comment: Noting that *instanceOf* is not very informative unless you know how the objects were constructed. It just checks that *MyObject.prototype* is on the [[Prototype]] chain of *newObject*.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` only returns "object", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof

What you probably want is this:
[How to get a JavaScript object's class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class)

Comment: How do you explain `typeof` returning `function` for `Function` instances?

Comment: ugh, am I confusing using instanceof with typeof?

Comment: Functions are also objects, but special function objects. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function (sorry for just posting links, a bit lazy tonight)

Comment: @Andreas Jansson, it's obvious. I'm just pointing out the inconsistency. `typeof []` would return `object`, not `array`, for example.

Comment: @katspaugh - that is how *typeof* is specified as behaving. It will return *function* for any native object that implements an internal [[call]] method.