# jQuery: some keys of objects cannot be accessed

Tags: jquery, object, each

Using jQuery, I have loaded some data to an object defined by `var tmp={}`.

Somehow the data will be displayed by `console.dir(tmp)`, but I cannot get some values by accessing it directly (e.g. `tmp.val`)!

The object I am storing data to is called `tmp` in the following example. Unfortunately, I cannot present the complete code how the data is gathered since it is too much.  What I can present is the output.

```
console.log(tmp)

$.each(tmp,function(key,val){
    console.log(key);
});
```

The fist line will display:

```
Object
  class: "modul7"
  class_name: "Some kind of class name."
  collectionRelevant: 1
```

The second code will display:

```
class
class_name
```

The `collectionRelevant` is missing.

I know my question is vague.

Has anyone stumbled over something like this? I have no clue anymore in which direction to seek the error.

Comment: Possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1249531/901048

Comment: What will be the output of `console.log( tmp.hasOwnProperty('collectionRelevant') )` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think native JavaScript should be enough for this task.

```
for( var key in tmp ) {
  // key
  console.log(key);
  // value
  console.log(tmp[key]);
}​​​​​ ​
```

Comment: That should be `for(var key in tmp)`.  Don't wanna be making global variables for no reason :-P