# js library to support various data structures? (like guava in java)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, data-structures, guava

Coming from Java I really like the flexibility afforded by the rich collection of data structures provided by Guava. Is there a "guava-like" library in js or jquery?

Note: I heard about closure and it seems a bit heavy - anything simpler? (or is closure really what I need?)

Note 2: by "rich collection of data structures" I mean sorted maps and sets, multimaps (duplicate keys allowed) and multisets (sets with multiple entries allowed - seems strange but actually very useful!), etc.

Comment: **Javascript is not Java**, so it's hard to provide whole Java / Guava goodies like Collections framework to Javascript...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by *"the rich collection of data structures" for JS* you meant utility for operating on JavaScript `Array`s and `Object`s and JavaScript itself, then I'd recommend [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

> Underscore is a utility-belt library for JavaScript that provides a
>   lot of the functional programming support. (...) Underscore provides
>   60-odd functions that support both the usual functional suspects: `map`,
>   `select`, `invoke` — as well as more specialized helpers: function
>   binding, javascript templating, deep equality testing, and so on. It
>   delegates to built-in functions, if present, so modern browsers will
>   use the native implementations of `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, `every`,
>   `some` and `indexOf`.

It also has Set-like functions like `union`, `intersection` and `difference`, type-checking functions isXXX (`isArray` etc.), function goodies and more stuff you'd write yourself without such a library.

Underscore has clean code, is well tested and [quite popular](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/) these days, I use it on daily basis in JS projects.

---

**EDIT** after question edit:

I know Guava has multimaps, multiset etc. but they are all consequesnce of Java design and it's hard to write 1 to 1 implementation of these collections in JS. It's because Javascript has **no**:

- static typing,
- classes in Java sense, uses prototyping instead (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249554/708434)),
- interfaces (but has functions as first-class objects on the other hand),
- easily defined object equality (`var t1 = { test: 1 }, t2 = { test: 1 }; t1 === t2` is `false`)

so it's hard to write general-use Set implementation, not mentioning Multiset or Multimap. There are for example some Set implementations like [Closure's one](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_structs_Set.html) or [this one](http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable/wiki/HashSet), but they are not perfect - first modifies elements inserted into Set (!), the second is not a mainstream, well-tested project (and personally I've never used it so can't say more).

In Javascript you just do `var multimap = { key: [ 1, 2, 3.0 ], key2: [ 4, 'test', { bla: null }, 1 ] }` and because of language design you can't just do `multimap.containsValue({ bla: null })`. I mentioned underscore.js because it has 95% utility functions you'll ever with JS collections, that is Arrays and Objects. If you want more, just use [Closure's structs](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_structs.html), but the library itself it's quite big.

Answer (score 6):

There is a now a lighter, faster alternative to Underscore.js: Lo-Dash (http://lodash.com/).

Answer (score 1):

## [js-sdsl](https://github.com/ZLY201/js-sdsl)

A javascript standard data structure library which benchmark against C++ STL.

This library has strict time complexity guarantee and can be used with confidence.

The latest beta version includes iterator functions which can be used like iterator in c++.

### Included data structures

- Vector
- Stack
- Queue
- LinkList
- Deque
- PriorityQueue
- Set (using RBTree)
- Map (using RBTree)
- HashSet (for reference only)
- HashMap (for reference only)

### Usage

To help you have a better use, we provide this [API document](https://zly201.github.io/js-sdsl/index.html).