# Does a new typeof operator (or function) exist for ECMA-5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I thought there are 5 primitive types for JavaScript (null, undefined, boolean, number, string), and then there is object (which includes array, function, and custom defined pseudo class objects).  But it is somewhat strange that

```
typeof null
```

is `"object"`, and there is no easy way to get back the object class name for pseudo-classical class such as `Person`, `Author`.  I wonder if there is a newer operator or function that can return possibly lower case names for primitive type (and `"null"` for `null`, not `"object"`), and capital case for custom-defined pseudo-classical objects?

If no such operator or function exist in ECMA-5 or later, would it make sense to have it?  Otherwise, we may need to rely on our own definition or any framework, but that will not be standard across different platforms.

Comment: No, there's no new operator. They considered fixing the `typeof` operator for ES6 so that it would return `"null"` instead of `"object"`, but backed away because it would break too much code.

Comment: I wonder maybe it can make sense if a new operator can be added instead... such as calling it `pseudoClassOf` or `typeOrClassOf`

Comment: The trouble with adding new operators is that any code out there that happens to have a variable with the same name will suddenly break. Since JS is so widely used, and since there's so much old code out there still in use, they're very sensitive about making changes that could break scripts. As such, they try to stick to the current reserved words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 5 objects have an internal property known as `[[Class]]`. This is the closest thing in ES5 to what you're asking.  You can access `[[Class]]` with `Object.prototype.toString` as follows:

```
function getClassOf(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
}

getClassOf([ ]); // => "Array"
getClassOf(new Date()); // => "Date"
getClassOf(function() { }); // => "Function"
getClassOf(3); // => "Number"
getClassOf(true) // => "Boolean"
getClassOf(document.createElement('div')); // => "HTMLDivElement"
getClassOf(Math); // => "Math"
getClassOf(null); // => "Null"
getClassOf(undefined); // => "Undefined"
getClassOf({ x: 1 }); // => "Object"
```

This behavior is crucial for adequately identifying objects which come from other frames.

However, it doesn't work for user-defined constructors. Objects created with user-defined constructors have `[[Class]]` `"Object"`.

```
function Foo() { }
var foo = new Foo();

getClassOf(foo); // => "Object"
```

It looks like ECMAScript 6 might have the ability to extend what's returned by `Object.prototype.toString`, so that `getClassOf(foo)` could be `"Foo"` through the `@@toStringTag` symbol.

See https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-September/025344.html for more information on the upcoming standard.

---

You could create your own function to do what you want like this:

```
function getTypeOf(value) {

    // Return "null" for null.
    if (value === null) return 'null';

    // Return primitive types.
    var type = typeof value;
    if (type != 'object') return type;

    // Return [[Class]] if available for objects.
    type = Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1);
    if (type != 'Object') return type;

    // Return "Object" if it wasn't created with another constructor.
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(value);
    if (proto == Object.prototype)
        return 'Object';

    // Return the constructor name if constructor hasn't been
    // modified on the object.
    if (value.constructor && proto === value.constructor.prototype)
        return value.constructor.name;

    // Return the constructor name if constructor hasn't been
    // modified on the prototype.
    if (proto.constructor && proto === proto.constructor.prototype)
        return proto.constructor.name;

    // Return "???" if the type is indeterminable.
    return '???';

}
```

Examples:

```
getTypeOf([ ]); // => "Array"
getTypeOf(new Date()); // => "Date"
getTypeOf(function() { }); // => "Function"
getTypeOf(3); // => "number"
getTypeOf(true) // => "boolean"
getTypeOf(document.createElement('div')); // => "HTMLDivElement"
getTypeOf(Math); // => "Math"
getTypeOf(null); // => "null"
getTypeOf(undefined); // => "undefined"
getTypeOf({ x: 1 }); // => "Object"

function Foo() { }
var foo = new Foo();

getTypeOf(foo); // => "Foo"

// If the constructor property is changed, still works.
foo.constructor = function FakeConstructor() { };
getTypeOf(foo); // => "Foo"

// If the constructor property AND the prototype's constructor is
// changed, result is "???".
foo.constructor = function FakeConstructor() { };
Foo.prototype.constructor = function FakeConstructor2() { };
getTypeOf(foo); // => "???"
```

Answer (score 1):

That behavior of `typeof` is dictated by the specification, [section 11.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3), Table 20:

> **Table 20 — typeof Operator Results**

```
Type of val                      Result
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Undefined                        "undefined"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Null                             "object"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Boolean                          "boolean"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number                           "number"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
String                           "string"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Object (native and does not 
implement [[Call]])              "object"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Object (native or host 
and does implement [[Call]])     "function"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Object (host and does not        Implementation-defined except may not be 
implement [[Call]])              "undefined", "boolean",  "number", or "string".
```

(Capitalized `Null` is an internal type whose sole value is `null`.)

This seems to be just a convention; `null instanceof Object` is `false`, so, as expected, `null` is clearly not an object.

The operator you're asking for does not exist. To figure out the names, you can use `=== null` to test for `null`, and `typeof` for the other primitives. As for "custom-defined pseudo-classical objects", the tools at your disposal are:

- [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)
- `function.`[`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype), `prototype`.[`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf)
- `object.`[`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

(List from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class), where you can see some examples.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this right now, in all browsers.

The `constructor` property of any object will return the function that owns that object's prototype.

```
function Person() { }
alert(new Person().constructor === Person) //true
```

Comment: but it depends on the `constructor` property being set correctly, which may not always be the case, and it won't work on `null` or `undefined` either

Comment: How could it possibly work on undefined? That doesn't even make sense... It doesn't make sense for null either (most of the time).

Comment: And there is nothing stopping someone overwriting the `constructor` property!

Comment: @jahroy: If you read the question it makes more sense. OP is asking if there's any operator that will return the function name for objects made from a custom constructor function, and a more sensible name for `null` instead of `"object"`.

Comment: @user1689607—the `constructor` property makes even less sense where objects are created using `Object.create`, where the `[[Prototype]]` is set without reference to a typical constuctor function.

Comment: @RobG: No, I'm saying that OP's comment at the top makes more sense when you read the question. I'm not saying using the `.constructor` property makes sense. But you're right, there wouldn't always be a useful name to use. There would need to be some default for objects that don't have a constructor.