# How can I test if two javascript objects are similar?

Tags: javascript, object

In Javascript (no jquery or other frameworks please) I want to test if 2 (or more) objects are the same type of object.

Here are some sample objects:

```
function Person (firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}
function Animal (name, type, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.age = age;
}
var family = {};
family.father = new Person ('John', 'Doyle', 33);
family.mother = new Person ('Susan', 'Doyle', 32);
family.pet = new Animal ('Jodie', 'Cat', 2);
```

Given the above objects, I want a generic way to test if family.father, family.mother, and family.pet are from the same "type" of object.  Can I test for the difference between Person and Animal in a generic way.  Something like:

```
if ( sourceObject(family.father) === sourceOjbect(family.mother) ) {
    alert('father and mother are the same type');
} else {
    alert('father and mother are not from the same object... we could have problems.');
}
if (sourceObject(family.pet) !== sourceObject(family.father)) {
    alert('the pet is a different type than the father');
} else {
    alert('Perhaps it should be a child instead of a pet?');
}
```

or perhaps something like this:

```
if (isSameObject(family.pet, family.father)) {
    alert('Perhaps it should be a child instead of a pet?');
} else {
    alert('Father and pet are different.');
}
```

There is no "sourceObject" function, but I'm trying to find out if there IS something that does this or someone has found a quick way to do that comparison.

Note I am not looking to compare the data in the objects, I am looking to compare the type of Objects involved in the comparison.  I need to do this without knowing the exact make up of the components involved.  For example, in the above code I could test for a "type" property, but that requires foreknowledge of the objects.  I am trying to write a generic function that will not necessarily know anything about the objects passed to it other than the objects them selves.

Comment: Could this SO question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/3123649

Comment: Would the `typeof` operator work?

Comment: @mathguy54 `typeof` would return `object` to all cases

Comment: @osi: No that would also compare the data in the object. So family.father and family.mother comparison would be false.

Comment: So `typeof` is usually used for comparing common objects like strings and numbers and arrays and stuff?

Comment: @mathguy54 have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare their constructors, as such

```
family.father.constructor == family.mother.constructor
```

MDC about constructors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8LvN5/

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the prototype, based on prototypical inheritance.

EDIT: might be better to compare constructors, for browser compatibility...

```
family.father.__proto__ == family.mother.__proto__ //EDIT: doesn't work in IE
//so
family.father.constructor == family.mother.constructor
```

so, in general:

```
function isSameObject(obj1, obj2){ //is same prototype - actaully;
   return obj1.constructor == obj2.constructor
}
```

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

Comment: family.father.prototype == family.pet.prototype gives true

Comment: Agreed. getting the prototype in that way doesn't work. edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use constructors: http://jsfiddle.net/uME8m/

```
alert(family.father.constructor === family.mother.constructor); //true
alert(family.father.constructor === family.pet.constructor); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare using `.constructor` or `.constructor.name`.

```
family.father.constructor == family.mother.constructor
family.father.constructor == family.pet.constructor
```

More on objects you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class).

If you want to construct a function, you can do:

```
function sourceObject(obj) {
  return obj.constructor; // you can return obj.constructor.name as well
}
```

Comment: @Dude yes, but I let a link to a similar question, where he can read more information about javascripts object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` ([MDN Resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)) to get the internal `[[prototype]]` property and then simply compare those two properties:

```
function isSameObject(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2);
}
```

This should work in every modern browser, starting with IE9.

The advantage compared to the `constructor` property, is that the `constructor` property can be easily accidentally overridden, for instance when implementing inheritance:

```
function A() {
}

function B() {
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

var b = new B();
console.log(b.constructor); //A
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgrNg/)**