# How to tell if two JavaScript instances are of the same class type?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm using [John Resig's Simple Inheritance Class](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) to define some classes, say:

```
var MyClass = Class.extend({});
var MyOtherClass = Class.extend({});
```

then I have some instances

```
var instanceA = new MyClass();
var instanceB = new MyClass();
var instancec = new MyOtherClass();
```

How can I determine if `instanceA` is of the same "type" as `instanceB`?

Note: I'm not asking to check if they are both a `MyClass`, I need to determine the class of one, and then see if the other is the same, regardless of whether they are `MyClass`s, `MyOtherClass`s or any other type.

Comment: instanceA.constructor == instanceB.constructor; (unless you re-define/delete the constructor property)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1249554/2079602

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you need to know if they are instances of the exact same class, (not subclasses of a common ancestor, etc) then this will work:

```
instanceA.constructor === instanceB.constructor
```

Comment: already posted as comment by @dandavis, you could have just asked him to post the answer, would have been nice. :)