# Find out whether a vector layer is a line or an area (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to make a distinction **if a vector layer** that's added to a leaflet map **is a line or an area**. My goal is to automatically generate a legend that has lines (colored by the `color` attribute and styled by `dashArray` of the `layer.options`) or areas (colored by the `fillColor` attribute), depending on the chosen layer. The Documentation doesn't say anything about a layer's type (or at least I didn't find anything).. so is this possible?

I tried `typeof layer` (that's `object`) and `layer.constructor` (`function e()`)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the objects in the layer and use `instanceof`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

For example:

```
myLayerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        // it's a marker, do stuff
    }
    if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
        // it's a polyline, do stuff
    }
    if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
        // it's a polygon, do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity - is there anything that would return the class like `L.Polyline`?

Comment: Not as far i know. You can try the options in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1249554/2019281 but to my knowledge they won't work on Leaflet's classes