# How to get the class name for an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets assume I have a class named `Foo` in JS:

```
Foo = function(){
    //properties
};
```

Now I'd like to know what class some object belongs to:

```
var fooObj = new Foo();
```

Is there a way to get the *name* of the class for my object `fooObj`, or even better using anonymous object of the class `this`?

The reason I want this is that using the name for a dynamically generated object's class, I would know what category it belongs to so that I can later *modify* properties of the object.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class