# Is it possible to get the class or class name from inside a function?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm trying to write debugging tools and I would like to be able to get the class name of the caller. Basically, caller ID.

So if I have a method like so, I want to get the class name:

```
public function myExternalToTheClassFunction():void {
   var objectFunction:String = argument.caller; // is functionInsideOfMyClass
   var objectFunctionClass:Object = argument.caller.this;
   trace(object); // [Class MyClass]
}

public class MyClass {

   public function functionInsideOfMyClass {
       myExternalToTheClassFunction();
   }
}
```

Is there anything like this in JavaScript or ActionScript3? FYI AS3 is based on and in most cases interchangeable with JS.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class, might help

Comment: Javascript doesn't have `public function` or type declarations after variables.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, you can ignore those. What I'm trying to get is the class the caller is in from a function external to that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html):

> Unlike previous versions of ActionScript, ActionScript 3.0 has no
>   `arguments.caller` property. To get a reference to the function that
>   called the current function, you must pass a reference to that
>   function as an argument. An example of this technique can be found in
>   the example for `arguments.callee`.
>
> ActionScript 3.0 includes a new `...(rest)` keyword that is recommended
>   instead of the arguments class.

Try to pass the `Class` name as argument:

**Class Code:**

```
package{

    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

    public class MyClass {

        public function functionInsideOfMyClass {

            myExternalToTheClassFunction( getQualifiedClassName(this) );

        }

    }

}
```

**External Code:**

```
public function myExternalToTheClassFunction(classname:String):void {

    trace(classname); // MyClass

}
```

Comment: FYI I tried passing `this` to the static method and that threw errors as well. It doesn't seem to throw any compiler errors if I create a variable, `var object:Object = this;` and pass `object` but didn't run it.

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behaviour. Take a look at this link and search the static method part. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes you can create an error then inspect the stack trace:

```
var e:Error = new Error();
trace(e.getStackTrace());
```

Gives you:

```
 Error
     at com.xyz::OrderEntry/retrieveData()[/src/com/xyz/OrderEntry.as:995]
     at com.xyz::OrderEntry/init()[/src/com/xyz/OrderEntry.as:200]
     at com.xyz::OrderEntry()[/src/com/xyz/OrderEntry.as:148]
```

You can parse out the "caller" method from there.

*Note that in some non-debug cases [`getStackTrace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#getStackTrace()) may return `null`.*