# get name of model/collection in mongoose pre save hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a mongoose pre save hook, I want to know the name of the model/collection, which I am saving in the pre save hook. From which variable can I get it.

```
module.exports = exports = function lastModifiedPlugin (schema, options) {
    schema.pre('save', function (next) {
        var self = this;

        self.constructor.findOne({ _id: self._id }, function (err, launch){
            console.log(" model " + self.mongooseCollection);
            console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
            console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(schema));

            next()
        });

    })

    if (options && options.index) {
        schema.path('lastMod').index(options.index)
    }
}
```

I tried to explore functions and properties of `this` and `schema` variable but could not got the name od model being saved.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get it from:

`self.constructor.modelName`