# Type Detection in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-deduction

Is there a way to get the ***name*** of a type of a caller of a function in TypeScript? Alternatively is there a way to get the ***name*** of the type of the current object?

Something like:

```
export class SomeData {
    sampleFunc() {
        console.log(this.getTypeName());
    }

    //or
    anotherFunc(caller: any) {
        console.log(caller.getTypeName());
    }
}
```

`getTypeName` is the desired functionality here. The types in TypeScript vanish after compiling. There is `typeof` (to get the class definition object itself) but I can not see how to get the *name*.

One usage for this could be cleaner logging with `console.group(name)` and `console.groupEnd()` - at least at development time.

**Edit:**

As far as I've searched, there is a [Polyfill for Metadata Reflection API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) proposal "*to add Decorators to ES7, along with a prototype for an ES7 Reflection API for Decorator Metadata*". One can use that cooperatively along with [decorators in TypeScript](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4).

Comment: Can you update  with a code sample of what exactly are you trying to achieve? I know you can use caller.name but getting type isn't possible as same rules apply as for JavaScript when TypeScript is compiled. Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3789144

Comment: @MatijaGrcic Thanks; I've updated the question. BTW on chrome, the `arguments.callee.caller.name` still gives the body of the function.

Comment: you may also want to try out http://vorlonjs.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my purposes I use:

```
caller.constructor.name
```

For more information you can read this excellent post:
[How to get a JavaScript object's class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class)

Comment: You're kidding me! :) Thanks!