# Get name of an object type in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I use `class.getName()` code in `JAVA` language to get the name of a object type. But how can I do that in `javascript` language? I can't find anything similar.

Comment: there is a good answer to exactly this question (updated in 2016) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typeof` or `instanceof`.

For more info, you can check this more detailed answer : [How to get a JavaScript object's class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class)