# How to differentiate a function from a class object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a js object that could be a function or a class, ie. it is equal to one of:

```
class {
  constructor( param ) {  }
  onCreate() { } 
};
```

Or,

```
function ( param ) { };
```

Turns out they have more in common then I expected (eg. both have a constructor).  Please tell me the simplest way to determine which of these types my js object refers to.

The solution must work in node 4.3.2.

edit: To clarify, the object that I'm trying to differentiate is a class or a function, not an instance of these.  And yes, I'm aware that a class is just syntatic sugar, that's what is making this difficult.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I have had the same problem to differentiate them because I could declare them either way and use them as class. Hopefully we'll get this sorted out.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking since your examples are not valid javascript. The key thing is that ES6 classes are just syntactic sugar, not a new type. Maybe it would help if you could add something outlining why you need to make this distinction.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve?  An ES6 class isn't really distinct from a function, it is another syntax to define a constructor function and set its .prototype property.

Comment: complete JS would definitely help. I assume that you have an object and you need to determine if it's been initialized via class or function. In that case, use `__proto__` as showcased in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this in the REPL with v6.9.2:

```
λ node -i
> class A {}
[Function: A]
> let B = function() {}
undefined
> A.toString()
'class A {}'
> B.toString()
'function () {}'
```

There may be another more reliable way, but checking for `class` should work:

```
if (A.toString().match(/^class/)) {
  // it's a class
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it worked for me, thanks.  Kinda' ugly, but I guess that's how it goes.

Comment: Well, it will work, on one particular implementation, unless someone decided to override  `.toString`, either on the individual object level or on a higher level e.g. `Function.prototype.toString`

Answer (score 2):

A `class` is not a "real thing" in the JavaScript specification beyond being syntactic sugar for the composition of pre-existing language primitives.

Vendors may make distinction possible (e.g. the `toString` method suggested in another answer), but I have scanned the spec and I don't think that is part of it... so is vendor-defined and therefore cannot be relied upon.

Indeed: Firefox 50 on the Mac does not print the word "class" (it uses the word "function") when `toString` is used on a `class`.

I don't know much about JS classes, so I could be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to these sorts of questions is almost always Lodash (or Underscore). Lodash has [isFunction](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#isFunction):

> Checks if value is classified as a Function object.

There are a *TON* of things in Lodash that people try to re-create all the time. Lodash is almost certainly doing it the right way and it's well-maintained.

Moral of the story: check if Lodash does X before you write a function to do X.

```
coffee> ld.isFunction
[Function: isFunction]
coffee> ld.isFunction(Date)
true
coffee> a = b:2
{ b: 2 }
coffee> ld.isFunction(a) 
false
coffee> 
coffee> d = new Date()
2016-12-17T00:02:58.950Z
coffee> ld.isFunction(d) 
false
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I just tried it and for me that function returns true in both cases (a function object vs a class object).

Comment: Are you talking about a constructor for a class?

Comment: As in my question above, an ES6 class object:  var c = class C { };  isFunction returns true for an ES6 class object.

Comment: I think you're asking a question that doesn't have an answer. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class

Comment: No, that's not it (the SO link you provided).  The Q does have an answer - the one I accepted.

Comment: I sure wouldn't use that in production code. If it does the job and it's not production, heck, why not.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it worth adding that, if one knows the names of the class or function, you can distinguish them like this.

```
> const C = class CC { };
undefined
> const F = function FF() { };
undefined
> C.prototype
CC {}
> F.prototype
FF {}
```

And if they are anonymous (not sure if that terminology is used in js) then you get just '{}'.

In a program you can use util.inspect (the name part dissapears with toString) to get at these strings.