# Check if object is a 'direct instance' of a class

Tags: javascript, class, object, instance, subclass

I have two classes:

```
class Bar extends Foo { // Foo isn't relevant
  constructor(value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Foo)) throw "InvalidArgumentException: (...)";
    super();
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Baz extends Bar {
  constructor(value) {
    super(value);
  }
}
```

The `Bar` `constructor` checks if `value` is an instance of Foo, it throws an error if it isn't. At least, that's what I wanted it to do. If you pass a `Bar` or a `Baz` as value, the if-statement returns `true` as well. The goal is to only let `Foo`s through.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class) already but that didn't really answer my question.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715426/9524541) from the other quesiton you linked seems to work. Only a Foo object created with `new Foo()` would return "Foo" when calling `foo.constructor.name`

Comment: What do you think you need this for? It seems like you are misusing inheritance, as your goal is to break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Don't do that. Every `Bar` and `Baz` instance should be valid where you want to have a `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the constructor:

```
if (!value || value.constructor !== Foo)
  throw 'InvalidArgumentException: (...)';
```

or the prototype of the object (this is more similar to what `instanceof` does):

```
if (!value || Object.getPrototypeOf(value) !== Foo.prototype)
  throw 'InvalidArgumentException: (...)';
```

Comment: This does not answer the core question. It does not solve the inheritance problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comparison between `Object.getPrototypeOf(yourObj)` and `Foo.prototype` to see if `yourObj` is exactly an instance of `Foo`. And you can move up the chain by just continuing to call `Object.getPrototypeOf` for each level.

Example:

```js
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}
class Baz extends Bar {}

const foo = new Foo();
const bar = new Bar();
const baz = new Baz();

// For this function:
// - level 0 is self
// - level 1 is parent
// - level 2 is grandparent
// and so on.
function getPrototypeAt(level, obj) {
    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    while (level--) proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
    return proto;
}

console.log("bar is a foo:", bar instanceof Foo);
console.log("baz is a foo:", baz instanceof Foo);
console.log("foo is exactly a foo:", getPrototypeAt(0, foo) === Foo.prototype);
console.log("bar is exactly a foo:", getPrototypeAt(0, bar) === Foo.prototype);
console.log("bar is direct child of foo:", getPrototypeAt(1, bar) === Foo.prototype);
console.log("baz is direct child of foo:", getPrototypeAt(1, baz) === Foo.prototype);
console.log("baz is direct child of bar:", getPrototypeAt(1, baz) === Bar.prototype);
console.log("baz is grandchild of foo:", getPrototypeAt(2, baz) === Foo.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should test if `value`'s internal `[[Prototype]]` is exactly `Foo.prototype`. You can get the internal `[[Prototype]]` with [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) :

```
if ( Object.getPrototypeOf( value ) !== Foo.prototype )
   throw "InvalidArgumentException: (...)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all of your classes you can use

```
if(!(value instanceof Foo && !(value instanceof Bar) && !(value instanceof Baz)))
```

Comment: @Sacha please see my answer for a generic check against other classes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the helper function:

```js
function isDirectInstanceOf(object, constructor) {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(object) === constructor.prototype;
}

console.log(
    isDirectInstanceOf([], Array), // true
    isDirectInstanceOf([], Object), // false
);
```

Comment: This is correct, but essentially the same answer as already given by Mohammad, CRice and Paul

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. Actually, I think my answer is still valuable since it suggested the separate function and is pretty illustrative and well-focused. What do you think?

Comment: If you want to focus on the helper function, I'd name it `isDirectInstanceOf` or (less accurate) `wasConstructedBy`. A "child" usually refers to a child class.

Answer (score -1):

I coined the function for checking relationships between DOM Classes and elements

```js
const getCreator = instance => Object.getPrototypeOf(instance).constructor.name;
// usage
getCreator(document.documentElement) === "HTMLHtmlElement;
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that all of your classes you reference are descendants of `Foo`. Such that `new Baz() instanceOf Bar && new Bar() instanceOf Foo === true`.
So when you ask is Bar instanceOf Foo, it will be true through inheritance.

Due to there being no Java `getClass()` equivalent in JS, you should use something like:

```
if (value.constructor.name !== Foo.name)
```

Comment: What does `getClass()` in Java do that `value.constructor` doesn't in JS?

Comment: You should never compare the names of classes. They might be mangled by minifiers, they might be optimised away, they might be overwritten or faked. Never rely on names.

Comment: @bergi can you please check my answer