# JavaScript check if object is an instance of current class

Tags: javascript

I'm in a situation where I need to check if an object is an instance of a child class but at the same time `instanceof` should return `false` for the parent class.

I have figured out a way but I'm not able to think of edge cases where this approach might fail.
Is this the correct way?

This is the simplified version of the code:

```
class Employee {
    static [Symbol.hasInstance]( instance ) {
        return Object.getPrototypeOf( instance ) === this.prototype;
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
}

class AssistantManager extends Manager {
}

const e1 = new AssistantManager( 'Dean' );

console.log( e1 instanceof Employee ) // false
console.log( e1 instanceof Manager ) // false
console.log( e1 instanceof AssistantManager ) // true
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea: changing how `instanceof` works will confuse every single person who ever deals with this code, including you once you've forgotten why you thought that was a good idea. If you want to know what *specific* class something is, check the constructor name.

Comment: Isn't it better to check the constructor name instead of changing the `instanceof` definition? `instanceof` is a widely used keyword and could seriously affect the maintainability of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code of someone trying to accomplish the same. It recommends checking the constructor. Might be helpful.

He mentions to check the constructor, like following:

```
if (!value || value.constructor !== Foo)
  throw 'InvalidArgumentException: (...)';
```

Or the prototype of the object (this is more similar to what instanceof does):

```
if (!value || Object.getPrototypeOf(value) !== Foo.prototype)
  throw 'InvalidArgumentException: (...)';
```

[Check if object is a 'direct instance' of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417099/check-if-object-is-a-direct-instance-of-a-class)

Comment: Please don't just link another question (which might get deleted), put the actual content itself in your answer as well.