# javascript get function namepace as shown in chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a function in namespace `lib.focus = function() ...`
This shows in the chrome debugger, but I need to get this as a string `lib.focus` from the object...
Any idea how I can do this? When I query it, it only shows me the contents of the object.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected result? Have you tried `JSON.stringify`? Have you tried getting the individual properties?

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class. I suspect that's what you want

Comment: Thanks, Ive tried these answers with no luck. Stringify errors out, and class names etc all return either 'Object' or 'MovieClip', not 'lib.focus'.

Comment: I think realistically your question is completely answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/get-the-name-of-an-objects-type. The summary is that you can't do what you want to do using javascript. How the console manages it, I don't know.