# How to get a Svelte component name?

Tags: svelte

How to know the name of a Svelte component from inside?

Somewhere in .svelte file:

```
    <script>
    console.log('name of this component is', ...)
    </script>
```

What's instead of the ellipsis?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: @dummdidumm logging

Answer (score 2):

You can give Svelte components a name by using the module context script:

```html
<script context="module">
  const name = 'whatever you want';
</script>

<script>
  console.log('name of this component is', name);
</script>
```

Code inside `<script context="module">` is run once and exists outside of the livecycle of the components. More in the docs: https://svelte.dev/docs#script_context_module

Is there another way? Svelte components are compiled to classes, but you don't have access to them (without crude, brittle hacks). Moreoever classes do not have a stable way to get their name. There's `constructor.name`, but that name could change when you minify your code (more on this here: [How to get a JavaScript object's class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class)). So the method above is the most consistent and "svelte" way to do this.

Comment: As a bonus to this, the importer can easily rename your component by doing `import ThatComponent from './ThisComponent.svelte'` so there is not even a way of knowing what they used.