# How to pass class as argument in function and print the class name in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a base class and I have inherited the functionality of base class into 3 other classes. Implemented hierarchical inheritance. But now I have to pass the class itself as parameter and print the class name. Any Suggestions?

Pasting the stack blitz link below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-f9xncx?file=index.ts

Comment: you mean like this? `Test2.printClassName(Porsche.name);`

Comment: @BennyYen But its saying ' error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeof Porsche'.'

Comment: or do you mean passing the instance and print its Class name? like this: `Test2.printClassName(new Porsche().constructor.name)`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bc1zyj?file=index.ts

Comment: Yes I need to pass the instance of  a class and print its class name

Comment: I can see its working on stackblitz but whenever I am running it on my IDE (Webstorm) below error is showing 

error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeof Porsche'.'

Comment: that's weird... did you use the `constructor` keyword? `const porsche = new Porsche(); console.log(porsche.constructor.name);`

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class?rq=1

Comment: Yes I have used the `constructor` keyword... Yah it is weird .. Its perfectly working fine on stackblitz but not locally..

Comment: It seems it works fine when i run `tsc index.ts --target es6` . But I have already defined the target in tsconfig. Not sure why is it not working when i am running just `tsc index.ts`

Comment: check out this: [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

> # Emit JS for just the index.ts with the compiler defaults
`tsc index.ts`

Comment: default target is es3 that's why

Comment: You're welcome : )