# Firing bullet with behaviour using js in gdevelop 5

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the FireBullet behaviour using JavaScript in [gdevelop5](https://wiki.gdevelop.io/gdevelop5/documentation). I added the following code to implement that:

```js
    var player = runtimeScene.getObjects("Player")
    let fireBullet = player[0].getBehavior('FireBullet')
    fireBullet.FireBullet()
```

The FireBullet function does not work on the behaviour. On debugging I found that the variable fireBullet is not undefined, and contains the behaviour as it’s value, but I don’t know which function to use to get the same result as the following image:
[image: image image 1193×48 6.49 KB]

The value of firebullet is found to be [object Object] in the debugger. I can't find a way to get the exact object, but it confirms that the behaviour is present.

Any help telling how to fire a bullet using the behaviour from js will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the result of the fireBullet variable here?

Comment: Sure thing. But the value is as far as I can get, unless I'm missing a method to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FireBullet()` isn't a method associated with `fireBullet` object. [`getBehavior()`](https://docs.gdevelop.io/GDJS%20Runtime%20Documentation/classes/gdjs.RuntimeObject.html#getBehavior) returns an object of type [`RuntimeBehavior`](https://docs.gdevelop.io/GDJS%20Runtime%20Documentation/classes/gdjs.RuntimeBehavior.html). [`activate()`](https://docs.gdevelop.io/GDJS%20Runtime%20Documentation/classes/gdjs.RuntimeBehavior.html#activate) method can be used to activate a behavior associated with this class.

So a solution could be:

```js
let player = runtimeScene.getObjects("Player")
let fireBullet = player[0].getBehavior('FireBullet')
fireBullet.activate(true)
```

Similarly, you can check out other methods of RuntimeBehavior and its child classes. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class) has helpful answers on how to find what class the corresponding object belongs to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So fireBullet.activate activates the fire bullet method/function in the behaviour or just activates the behaviour ? If it only activates the behaviour, which it seems to because it does not fire a bullet, how do I actually run the fireBullet function in the behaviour and fire a bullet? The fireBullet behaviour has multiple functions, like fireBullet(), fireBulletTowardsPosition and so on, so how can I run those? Also is there any documentation for javascript in gdevelop?

Comment: The docs say it just activates the behavior. The closest thing I could find to js docs for gdevelop were these: https://wiki.gdevelop.io/gdevelop5/events/js-code, https://docs.gdevelop.io/GDJS%20Runtime%20Documentation/. You can check different method names associated with fireBullet, or go through RuntimeBehavior methods to figure out how to find the methods you are looking for.