# JavaScript: How to refer to subclassed (and possibly overridden) static properties

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet, I wish to have a class variable `foo`. Subclasses of `A` may or may not override the static variable `foo`. In the following example it prints `undefined` for all three print statements. How can I refer to the most recent static variable in the MRO? (i.e. I can't hardcode the class name in `run` because it maybe be subclassed).

```js
class A {
   static foo = "default"
   run() {
      console.log(this.foo)  // this needs to point to this class here
   }
}

class B extends A {   
}

class C extends A {
   static foo = "overridden"   
}


a = new A()
a.run()  // Expecting "default"

b = new B()
b.run()  // Expecting "default"

c = new C()
c.run()  // Expecting "overridden"
```

Comment: Static properties are properties of the class itself, not properties of the instances (`this` in `run` refers to an instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

> The static keyword defines a static method or property for a class, or a class static initialization block (see the link for more information about this usage). **Neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself.**

You could, [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744621/19068), access the `constructor` of the instance like so:

```js
class A {
   static foo = "default"
   run() {
      console.log(this.constructor.foo)
   }
}

class B extends A {   
}

class C extends A {
   static foo = "overridden"   
}


a = new A()
a.run()  // Expecting "default"

b = new B()
b.run()  // Expecting "default"

c = new C()
c.run()  // Expecting "overridden"
```

… but this is probably a design mistake and you shouldn't be making the property `static` in the first place.

Comment: Why is it a design mistake to use static variables in the first place?