# Checking for types of objects in my script?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a localStorage wrapper to make inserting and retrieving data easier when needing it to do more robust queries.

My script is here:
https://github.com/OscarGodson/storageLocker

A user of my script asked me how he could save a Date and i told him the proper procedure (save `new Date().getTime()` to the JSON and revive it with something like `new Date(json.time)` but he was trying to do `hisStorage.save({'the_date':new Date()})`, but to his surprise when he went to get the data it'd be malformed.

So, my question is, how can I catch inserts like this and other objects (maybe events?), convert them for the users to be stored in the JSON and also retrieved properly? I've been working on it all day and i can't figure out how to check for certain types of objects and convert accordingly via some switch case.

The save and retrieve part of my script looks like this:

**Saving Data:**

```
storageLocker.prototype.save = function(value){
    var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.catalog));
    if(json == null){json = {};}
    for(var key in value){
        if(value.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            json[key] = value[key];
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem(this.catalog,JSON.stringify(json));
    return this;
}
```

**Getting Data:**

```
storageLocker.prototype.get = function(value){
    json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.catalog));
    if(json == null){json = {};}
    if(value){
        if(typeof json[value] !== 'undefined'){
            return json[value];
        }
        else{
            //Makes it so you can check with myStorage.get('thisWontExist').length
            //and it will return 0 and typeof will return object.
            return new Object('');
        }
    }
    else{
        return json;
    }
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `instanceof` operator to check whether the property is an instance of `Date`:

```
if (value[key] instanceof Date) {
    //serialize in some way
    ...
}else{
    json[key] = value[key];
}
```

The problem is; in the getter, how are you going to know which values need to be revived again? You'll have to rely on some string format and accept that if the user saves a string in this format, then it will be revived as a date.

Comment: Yes, this is also true. I'm thinking about some custom date store like (in localStorage) `sLDate(123467890)` or something. If you have other suggestions let me know. Thanks a lot, i'll try it out. The previous person who tried to help me said it'd be impossible since you can't store objects in JSON... so i thought i'd ask again :)

Comment: Well, you cannot store objects in JSON, but you can store its serialized values. About the format, go for one of the already used ones, like '/Date(12345...)/' which is used by ASP.NET AJAX etc..

Comment: Sounds good I was just trying to be unique so that it wouldn't ever be written over but yours should work. But if you cant store objects in JSON how is those instanceof goon to work with my script? (users give json to my script to then store in localStorage? In firebug and stuff I can see the date object too

Comment: Your users pass objects to be stored right? Iterate over the properties before serializing and exchange Date objects with their string representations. Use `instanceof` to identify Date objects.