# Why is "window.location instanceof Location" false in IE?

Tags: javascript, dom, typechecking

I tested the following code in FF 3.6 and IE 8. The former alerts `true`, the latter alerts `false`. Why is this and how can I accomplish the same behavior in both browsers? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            alert(window.location instanceof Location);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what is the purpose of this check? I don't think such internal class names (Location, HTMLElement, etc.) are shared completely across browsers, so it might be helpful to know what you're trying to do to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Interesting observation: getting the Constructor name of the location object in IE also fails. Using the technique in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: I'm working on a jQuery plugin which maps URL anchors to JS functions. The plugin takes an argument which either can be a DOM element or a `Location` object. So I need a way to check what kind a given argument is. :)

Comment: I updated my answer. You'll be better off testing for the `nodeType` property that will be present if it was an DOM element. Then you could also test for some of the properties of the `location` object if desired. Of course someone could pass in some other object that has those properties, so it isn't absolutely perfect. But if someone is using your plugin, it wouldn't seem likely that they would try to defeat the test like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** With regard to the comment under your question, it sounds like you need to test for the difference between a DOM element, and a Location object.

You'll probably be better off testing for the DOM element using the `nodeType` property.

```
if( obj.nodeType ) {
    // it was a DOM element
}
```

Then you can test for various properties if `nodeType` wasn't found, just to be certain it is a `location` object.

```
if( obj.nodeType ) {
    // it was a DOM element
} else if( obj.hostname && obj.pathname ) {
    // it was a location object
} else {
    // some ERROR
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

This works for me in Chrome, Safari, Firefox:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(window.location) == '[object Location]';
```

I can't test in IE right this minute, though.

This is the method noted in the ECMAScript spec [Section 8.6.2](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2) for getting the internal `[[Class]]` property name.

Comment: Returns `[object Object]` in IE. :(

Comment: @Philippe: Yes, just got done testing it too. If this is needed, you may need to do a couple of separate tests including [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630313/why-is-window-location-instanceof-location-false-in-ie/4630355#4630355) from [@Phrogz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz). EDIT: Although that one seems to fail in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.constructor == Location
```

Works in IE and Firefox; does not work in Chrome. (There is no `Location` object in Chrome.) Would only work if you are testing the location from the same window as your script is running in, however.

What are you really trying to do?