# A clean way of checking whether an object is an instance of window.constructor

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objects

The title pretty much says it all. I need to check whether an object is an instance of the DOM:Window interface. `window` will pass the test, `window.frames[xyz]` as well, should the iframe exist.

The most intuitive way appears to be a simple instanceof check via `object instanceof window.constructor`. It's a sad state of affairs that there are browsers *(like IE6)*, whose `window.constructor` equals to `undefined`.

What would you suggest? There are always hacky, ugly and `toString` dependant ways like `/\[object.*window.*\]/i.test(object)`, but I would rather go for a simple, clean solution, if possible.

Comment: You can find a good explanation of how to detect object in javascript and about the problems using each technique.

worth the read... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript`

Answer (score 6):

The `window` object has the unusual property [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.window), which always points to the same `window` object. It would be *very* unlikely for any other object to replicate this behaviour, so you could use it as a fallback to the `window.constructor` test:

```
function isWindow(obj) {
    if (typeof(window.constructor) !== 'undefined') {
        return obj instanceof window.constructor;
    } else {
        return obj.window === obj;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle showing this behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/YG2da/1/)

Comment: Nice, it indeed works in all the browsers I could throw it at (IE 7+, Firefox, Chrome).

Comment: I found another inconsistency: `window.open() instanceof window.constructor` equals `false`. Seems like the DOM:Window interfaces of different DOM instances don't share the same pointer, which is quite unfortunate indeed. `obj.window === obj` is rather solid, but I was looking forward to offering a nice, standardized way to those browsers that'd support it.

Comment: I tried to utilise the non-standardised, yet widely supported `Function.prototype.name` property: `window.constructor?(obj instanceof window.constructor || (obj.constructor instanceof Function && obj.constructor.name?obj.constructor.name === window.constructor.name:obj.window === obj)):obj.window === obj`

Comment: Why is it that if `window.constructor` is `undefined`, the function checks if the object is an instance of it? Shouldn't `===` be `!==`?

Comment: @GustvandeWal Yes, it should. Fixed.