# how to return objects interface name/type?

Tags: javascript

Is there a function or something to get the interface of an object?

Like, for `<p/>` = `HTMLParagraphElement`, how would I retrieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are just one way to do so: fetch a list of all available interfaces, iterate via this list and check your variable value for type using `instanceof` operator.

This way should work like following:

```
var element = ... // here your element comes
var interfaces = [HTMLParagraphElement, HTMLDivElement];
var interface = interfaces.filter(function (x) { return element instanceof x; })[0].toString();
```

Now you get something like `function HTMLParagraphElement() { [native code] }` in interface variable (if element is `<p />`). I assume this only works for V8 (Google Chrome). Now you can use regexies to extract interface name.

```
interface.match(/function (.+)\(\)/)[0]
```

To get list of all interfaces you can use following (works only for HTML elements):

```
var interfaces = [];
for (var key in window) {
  if (key.indexOf('HTML') == 0)
    interfaces.push(window[key]);
}
```

I agree with duri's answer, so you don't need to enumerate all interfaces, using of `constructor` method is more easy way to get prototype function. After that you can use regex I wrote to extract interface name.

Comment: And how would I list all available interfaces?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `document.createElement('p').constructor`, this returns the `HTMLParagraphElement` object.

If you want to get just the name of the interface (as a string), call `toString()` method on the object (you'll get result similar to `[object InterfaceName]`) and parse it using some string methods (e.g. regular expressions): `document.createElement('p').toString().match(/^\[object (.*)\]$/)[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript), the simple and generic solution:

```
document.getElementById("myPElement").constructor.toString()
```

That can return two kind of values (it depends on web browser):

1. (Best case) A String like `"[object HTMLParagraphElement]"`
2. A String like:`"function HTMLParagraphElement() { [native code] }"`

Now, you must do some workaround to get the job done, use a Regular Expression to execute against the two possible strings and extract the Interface Name.

```
var strConstr = myPElement.constructor.toString();
//Match "[object HTMLParagraphElement]":
new RegExp(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/).exec(strConstr)[1]; 
//Match "function HTMLParagraphElement() { [native code] }"
new RegExp(/function (.+?)(/).exec(strConstr)[1];
```

Both expressions extract the "HTMLParagraphElement" part

**Warning: Avoid the IE quirks mode, it will fail**