# GetType() in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

how do i achieve this c# code in javascript

```
protected void Validate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var _typeName = sender.GetType().FullName;
}
```

i want to add the Validate in all RadControls (telerik) and i wanna check if the sender is type of *RadDatePicker*

i tried this but its not working so i wanna check if what is the type name of the sender.

```
if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker.isInstanceOfType(sender)) 
{
    alert("it is a datepicker");
}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need

```
var toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}

.......

var theTypeIs = toType("Bresleveloper");
```

result will be "string"

(from here [Better way to get type of a Javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390426/better-way-to-get-type-of-a-javascript-variable))

Comment: it just returns an "object"

Comment: run this code : var toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}

toType("Bresleveloper")

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`type`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/)

`type(sender); //will return you the type of control you are using`

Comment: throws "type is not defined". Where would you get "type" from?

Comment: Jquery.type(sender)