# Cross browser way of getting variable type name in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get an object's name in all browsers **OR** how to get an object's type name in IE ?

[image]

Relevant posts [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390426/better-way-to-get-type-of-a-javascript-variable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript/332429#332429).

In this case the Matrix object is defined in an external package. I just need the name of the type - i'm not interested in a thousand `instanceof`'s ...

**EDIT**

I'll be more specific about my problem. [This is `Matrix` declaration](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/blob/master/dist/math.js#L3013) from `math.js`. I've got a result object and i want to check if it's a Matrix. Math.js has some types of it's own (like Matrix, Unit) but it also uses common types like String, Number and Array. I'm trying to get the result type as string and i'm trying to avoid checking each type specifically.

Comment: The easiest way that will always work is to define a type field at prototype level that spells the type.

Comment: `result.value || result.value.constructor`?

Comment: `typeof` returns a string representation for type. For string it returns "string" for objects "object" so on and so forth....can you elaborate what you mean by 'name' of type?

Comment: @Bart - it's an external package and i'm trying to avoid intrusive solutions.

Comment: What specifically about the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript/332429#332429 doesn't answer your question here?

Comment: @Vikram - as you said - `Typeof` will return `object` and i'm looking for `Matrix` here.

Comment: @Andy E - It's working as expected in Firefox and Chroome - but not in IE.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe what you're actually trying to accomplish, we might have a better idea exactly what solution would help you.  There are a zillion ways to look at the "type" of an object so without knowing what you're actually trying to do, we can't really advise which way to go.

Comment: @jfriend00 Very good point

Comment: @haki: there's a solution provided for IE in that answer.

Comment: I've edited the original post with more specific details. Thanks.

Comment: Yo heads up `Matrix` isn't supposed to be exposed by `math.js` so you're going behind theyre back by doing this. If you use their minified code or try using a different version of the project this may break. You really should never rely on constructor names

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to get an object's name

Objects don't have names.

> ```
> result.value.constructor
>  > function Matrix(data) {
> ```

That means `Matrix` is a function, which do have names.

However, using using [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) to get it is a non-standard behavior which shouldn't be relied on.

As you have discovered, it only works in [some implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: IE = Headache. Any creative corresponding solutions for IE ?

Comment: @haki AFAIK there isn't a good solution. But you could try converting the function to an string, and parsing its name.

Answer (score 1):

Using the name of the constructor is not reliable: not supported by all browsers, and the name may be mangled when a library is minified or obfuscated.

There are two ways to reliably determine the type of objects:

1. Using `instanceof`, i.e.

   ```
   if (result instanceof Matrix) console.log('Result is a matrix');
   ```
2. All object prototypes you are interested in should be given a special property like `_type` describing their type, so you can just check

   ```
   if (result._type === 'Matrix') console.log('Result is a matrix');
   ```

In the case of math.js, you can just use the function `typeof` to get the type of any primitive or math.js specific type. Returned types are lower case.

```
console.log(math.typeof(result));   // 'matrix'
console.log(math.typeof(1.23));     // 'number'
console.log(math.typeof('hello'));  // 'string'
```