# Getting an error while loading map: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying Google maps API. In which I am using Google DirectionsService to plot a route on a map.

I have few already stored DirectionResults objects. which I want to load onto the map.
Below is the code I have written;

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

To load stored json (DirectionsResult object format)

```
$.getJSON('GoogleJson.json', function (json) {
    debugger;
    data = json;
});
```

Calling DirectionsService.Route() method;

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(data);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

This is giving an error. If we use response object in `setDirections()` it renders the map with route. However, if I load it from a file using `getJSON()` method, it gives above error.

In above code, if we view the data and response objects, both are same.

EDIT:
I added checks as

```
if (data != response) {
    console.log(typeof data);
    console.log(typeof response);
}

if (data == response)
    alert('both objects are same');
```

The objects doesn't seem to be same. The `typeof` statement says both are of object type.

Comment: Apparently, `data !== response`. Can you `console.log(typeof data); console.log(typeof response);` for us?

Comment: I added checks as per your suggestions, if (data != response) {
                        console.log(typeof data);
                        console.log(typeof response);
                    }

                    if (data == response)
                        alert('both objects are same'); The objects doesn't seem to be same. The typeof statement says both are of object type.

Comment: Hm, and using [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7390612/1835379), what does `toType(data)` and `toType(response)` return? And better yet, what are the contents of both variables?

Comment: If we see the contents of both the objects, it gives us format similar to DirectionsResult object as, routes[].legs[].steps[] collection.

Comment: Your object `data` has to be `google.maps.DirectionsResult` object. It seems it's not.

Comment: Can we convert it to DirectionsResult instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data contains exactly `routes` as expected for `directionsDisplay.setDirections`(I don't think so): There is another, undocumented property in a directionsResult which is required(a function that returns the original request). The name of this function is dynamic, so it may:

1. not be stored in a JSON(because it's a function)
2. not be restored securely in any manner(because you don't know the expected name of the function)

conclusion: a direction may not be created by a stored directionsResult(at least not secure across sessions)

The only workaround I can think of is to store the original request too , send a dummy-request to retrieve the desired name for the function and then restore the function with this name.

Comment: are there any other ways ? I don't want to use Google service data, but the data which is provided by some person, admin in this case.

Comment: Not getting it clearly. response is a original result where as data is stored result. Which function should we restore and how ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was function(maybe it has changed), now it's a plain object that contains the request(1st argument usually passed to `route()`). The name of this object currently for me is `Tb` . It must contain at least the `travelMode` .

Comment: yes tb is present in both the objects with the same values in respective properties.

Comment: can you post the json?

Comment: I have uploaded the DirectionsResult json on below link, https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqh0fh4tjlys7d2/GoogleJson.json

Comment: This JSON may not work. You've stored the response from the directionsService which contains dynamic property-names which are not stable across sessions(e.g. Ba, j, ra ....and so on). For a valid directionsResult these properties must be converted to the corresponding instances of the google.maps-classes(LatLng, LatLngBounds). The documentation for a directionsResult is located at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult   **However, the stored  JSON is the response of a google-service, you're not allowed to store these data .**