# How many data types are there in JS, and what are they?

Tags: javascript, types

I started reading a book, Javascript for Kids. In it the author states that there are three data types:

- numbers
- strings
- booleans

However, according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp), there are four:

- numbers
- strings
- arrays
- objects

I wanted to know which one is correct.

Comment: Don't forget Symbol and BigInts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can test it using `typeof` operator:

The `typeof` operator gives you the names of data types when placed before any single operand.

Hence, try using `typeof` with any operand variable: it will give one of the following datatype names:

1. String
2. Number
3. Boolean
4. Object
5. Undefined

Hence, these are the five data Types in Javascript.

```
var val1 = "New World";   //returns String
var val2 = 5;             //returns Number
var val3 = true;          //returns Boolean
var val4 = [1,2,3];       //returns Object
var val5 = null;          //returns Object (Value is null, but type is still an object)
var val6;                 //returns Undefined
```

Comment: Wouldn't `val4` be considered an array?

Comment: Its value type is definitely an array, but since Javascript can only categorise it as one of the aforementioned datatypes, it places Array into object category. It treats it as a special object though, but definitely under Object.

Comment: @eagercoder No, the _type_ is an object, the _instance_ is of an `Array`. You’ll learn about prototypes, eventually: arrays aren’t really treated in a special way. They are just object that have the `Array` interface and thus supports method like `sort`, `map`, `filter`, etc. Every object is an instance of some function (in this case `function Array()`) and thus implements it as a prototype.

Comment: If you check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp ,
you will find W3Schools mentioning following line:
"In JavaScript, an array is a special type of object. Therefore typeof [1,2,3,4] returns object"
@Xufox :you just said what I said, that its type is Object.
Although, its not clear from your comment, WHICH type are you talking about.
DataType or ValueType?
which I just clearly mentioned already to eagercoder that, its Datatype is OBJECT while its Value Type is Array. Simple as that.

Comment: @svik [I wouldn’t listen to W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). There’s absolutely nothing special about an array. The only special thing is one way to write an array literal: `[2,4,6]`. But that has nothing to do with data types, only with syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Things aren't actually as straightforward as they described in answers above... they usually aren't in javascriptland ;)

`typeof` is the 'official' function that one uses to get the `type` in javascript, however in certain cases it might yield some unexpected results ...

**1. Strings**

`typeof "String"` or
`typeof Date(2011,01,01)`

> "string"

**2. Numbers**

`typeof 42` or
`typeof NaN`, lol

> "number"

**3. Bool**

`typeof true` (valid values `true` and `false`)

> "boolean"

**4. Object**

`typeof {}`    or
 `typeof []` or
 `typeof null` or
`typeof /aaa/` or
 `typeof Error()`

> "object"

**5. Function**

`typeof function(){}`

> "function"

**6. Undefined**

`var var1; typeof var1`

> "undefined"

[Alternative is to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390426/better-way-to-get-type-of-a-javascript-variable) `({}).toString()` which will get you somewhat more accurate answer most of the time...

Answer (score 3):

Check the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

- Six data types that are primitives:

  1.Boolean

  2.Null

  3.Undefined

  4.Number

  5.String

  6.Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)
- and Object

Comment: Wait… `null` is not a type. That’s nothing that `typeof` would return.

Comment: if mozilla says null is a data type, End of Stroy. anyway there has been several issues related to that. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @Fawzan But type null is categorized as "Object"

Answer (score 2):

There are 6 basic data types in JavaScript:

1. A **number**
2. A **string**
3. A **boolean** (logical type)
4. The “**null**” value
5. The “**undefined**” value
6. Objects and Symbols

For more detail you can go through this link -
https://javascript.info/types

Answer (score 1):

The latest ECMAScript standard defines eight data types, namely:
Seven data types that are primitives:
Boolean, 
Null, 
Undefined, 
Number, 
BigInt, 
String, 
Symbol 
and Object
For more information, refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#BigInt_type