# How can I tell if a parameter passed to a function is an object or a string?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
error = (error, modelState, modalHeader, modalBody): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    // function code here
```

In some cases the first parameter could be a string such as:

```
"problem"
```

in other cases it could be an object such as this:

```
{
"ErrorMessage":"END_TEST - Invalid TestID, Unauthorized Access or TestStatus is not Started or Paused",
"ErrorNumber":50001
}
```

Is there a way that I could detect if it is a string or an object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390426/better-way-to-get-type-of-a-javascript-variable

Comment: Can you give an example of how the typeof could be used for this so I can make the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is your friend:

```
error = (error, modelState, modalHeader, modalBody): ng.IPromise<any> => {
   if (typeof error === 'string') {
     //string
   } else if (typeof error === 'object') {
     //object
   }
}
```

`typeof` can evaluate to following: `string`, `number`, `object`, `undefined`, `boolean`, `function`.