# Object.prototype.toString() - trying to get 'String' instead of [object String]

Tags: javascript, prototype, typeof

I am trying to get the type of an argument by not using the typeof. Also (its part of an exercise) I must use Object.prototype.toString...

Calling the function should return (for example if its a string) "String". However, my code returns String]

How can I remove the bracket?
Thanks!

```
function types(x){

   var array = Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
    var arr= array.split(" ");
   return arr[1];
}
```

types("hello");

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: Just `Object.prototype.toString.call(x).slice(8, -1)`

Comment: That doesn't work! I want it of course to be general- for a string it should return "String" for Number 'Number' etc. If I use substring .substring(start,end) -for example "Number" and "String" have a different length so thats pointless

Comment: This problem is solved in other posts. look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7390612/5728894

Comment: .slice(0,-1); Will always return the whole string except the last character.

Comment: yea it actually works if I remove the split()-and only because I know how many letters the word object includes so I can say slice(8,-1) otherwise it wouldn't work

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Seems an odd task. What if the object in question implements `toString()` and returns something else?

Comment: @learningcoding: The point is that the `[object ` prefix always is the same. It *will* work,being both simple and efficient. You don't need to `split` anything dynamically.

Comment: @Phil: That's exactly why you call `Object.prototype.toString` upon the object, instead of invoking its own `toString` method.

Comment: @Bergi ah, I missed that. Good point

Comment: you should first `delete Object.prototype.toString;` before you use `Object.prototype.toString.call()` in case another script mucked it up. also, why not just use `.replace(/\W/g,"")` on any output if unsure of the format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have to use Object.prototype.toString as native string is not an object.  If you force it on a string, then it will return the "[object String]".

If you want the type of a variable, then you can simply use the following function

```
var types = x => x.contructor.name;
```

If you must, then you use the following

```
var types = x => Object.prototype.toString.call(x).match(/\[object (.*)\]/)[1];
```

This is inefficient as you first wrap the original variable with an object variable, then call its toString function, followed by a regExp (or substr).

Comment: OP says it's part of an exercise and they must use `toString`

Comment: **Warning:** `x.constructor.name` will error if x is `null` or `undefined`. Do not use this in any situation where you are unsure of the variable's type.

Answer (score 0):

This will return `String`. Uses [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to remove the trailing `]`

```
function types(x) {
   var array = Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
   var arr = array.split(" ");
   return arr[1].slice(0, -1);
}
console.log(types('hello')) // String
```