# Best way to check data type fields in JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, instanceof, typeof

I have few fields that I'm getting from my .txt field and I want to check their type(string, int, date). Also I want to check the length at the same time and I want to allow nulls for some of these fields. I tried to use `typeof` but that did not work the way it should or I'm missing something in my code. Here is few fields from my .txt file:

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  BIRTH_DATE  GRADE
Mike        Hart       5/24/2002   7
John        Cook       11/05/2003  6
Renn        Voos       4/17/2001   9
```

Here is my code that I used:

```
for(var j=0; j < allLines.length; j++){
    var columns = allLines[j].split('\t');
    for(var k=0; k < columns.length; k++){
        console.log(typeof(columns[0]));
    }
}
```

I noticed the problem when I was checking `typeof` columns[2] that is BIRTH_DATE(`datetime`) I was getting 'string' in my console.log. Also when I check for columns[3] that is `integer` I was getting `string` in my console.log. I'm wondering if I have to do the trim for these values or something else causing the problem and I'm getting type of `string` for all fields. What is the best way to check for data types? I was looking in JavaScript and JQuery and type of looks like the most reliable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to get type of a Javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390426/better-way-to-get-type-of-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: [Javascript is an untyped language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language). Types are rather maluable so this kind of thing is difficult at best.