# Given an input value, return the typeOf the value as a String?

Tags: javascript

Types are one of:

```
 *    - "string"
 *    - "array"
 *    - "object"
 *    - "undefined"
 *    - "number"
 *    - "boolean"
 *    - "null"
 *    - "function"
 *    - "date"
 * 
 * Examples:
 *    typeOf(134) -> "number"
 *    typeOf("javascript") -> "string"
 *    typeOf([1,2,3]) -> "array"
```

Comment: Please post what you have so far. You might start with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to get type of a Javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390426/better-way-to-get-type-of-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: This sounds like homework but it doesn't matter. The list of types is missing  primitive data types `symbol` and `bigint` which really need to be in it - or how to accommodate them should have been included in the exercise.

Comment: @traktor53@Johnny Mopp@ggorlen Thanks, everyone. It is classwork and I'm just stuck. Working multiple codes and needed a little help.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript actually has a `typeof` keywod:

```
console.log(typeof 134) // 'number'
console.log(typeof 'javascript') // 'string'
```

The only tricky part is:

```
console.log(typeof [1, 23, 4]) // object
```

Because arrays are technically objects.  To separate them, you could  look at if the value was array-like, eg. check if it has a `length` property ... or you could use a third-party function (eg. Lodash has an `isArray` function).

Comment: `typeof []` -> `"object"` though. Better to just close it as a dupe (see above).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function typeOf(unknown) {
  if (Array.isArray(unknown)) {
    return 'array';
  }
  return typeof unknown;
}

console.log(typeOf(134));
console.log(typeOf("javascript"));
console.log(typeOf([1,2,3]));
```