# Why can't I do forEach on a selection box's options?

Tags: javascript

Here is some output from the console that illustrates my question

```
var a=document.createElement("select"); <ENTER>
undefined

a.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));  <ENTER>
<option>​</option>​

a
<select>​…​</select>​

a.options
[<option>​</option>​]

a.options[0];
<option>​</option>​
```

So far, so good.
But now

I type `a.options.`  and I am to type forEach but I notice forEach isn't getting listed.

```
 a.options.forEach(function() {});
VM1048:2 Uncaught TypeError: a.options.forEach is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:11
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Yet a.options so looked like an array

And forEach definitely works for arrays, no error.

```
a=[1,2];
[1, 2]
typeof a
"object"
a.forEach(function(){});
undefined
```

I guess the options of a selection box maybe aren't an array.. so what are they?

I've heard of the 'arguments' pseudo-array.. I guess perhaps a selection box's 'options' is like that? / some object that has similar syntax to array?

Comment: further to user286's  answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `options` is *not* an Array; it is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). As such it does *not* have a forEach function-member.

> The HTMLCollection interface represents a generic collection (array-like object) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list.

One could use `call` with `Array.prototype.forEach`, since an HTMLCollection is array-like<sup>1</sup>:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function ..)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The HTMLCollection interface has a `length` property and allows positional access via the indexer.

Comment: Is there a way to view that it is HTMLCollection , in code?  (since I see that typeof just says object).

Comment: @barlop I'd open up another question for that; I'm not sure of a "good" way to do so. What about seeing if it's array-like but *not* an array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893776/the-most-accurate-way-to-check-js-object-type    var a=document.getElementsByTagName("*");  Object.prototype.toString.call(a);

Comment: @barlop Whoops. I messed up that syntax. In any case I would still recommend *not* 'checking for' the specific type but instead rely on [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and proper adherence to contractual documentation. For instance, for the options, as in the original question, Chrome yields "[object HTMLOptionsCollection]" instead of the more generic "HTMLCollection". Furhermore, I have no idea if these results are consistent across browsers (I have a feeling it depends a good bit on how the DOM API is exposed, by W3C and implementation).

Comment: @barlop Basically there doesn't appear to be a need to tell what 'type' of collection it is; other than perhaps if it is *not* a proper array. Contractual method documentation can further mandate either an "array" or an "array-like" object pushing any required conversion process into the caller and handled as a suitable type of duck at the usage site.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by user2864740 is excellent.

I will give an example of how to get access to options based on the provided solution and display text content of all of them in the console:

```
var select = $('#selector_here');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(select.options, function(option, index) {
  console.log('option ' + (index + 1) + ':', option.textContent);
  /* do some required magic here */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
Object.values(document.getElementById("myElementID").options).forEach(element => console.log(element));
```