# Getting __noSuchMethod__() { [native code] } is not a constructor function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am getting this wired error in jmeter, "function **noSuchMethod**() { [native code] } is not a constructor function" when I try to look for logout element and click on it. So I have couple functions written in the Webdriver sampler and if I try to logout without calling the other function then it works normally. In the below code if I run the verifyEmailBatchListed(emailBatchName,counterVal) script then the logout function is failing to find the element and throwing this noSuchMethod error. I am not sure what wrong I am doing. I even checked if the element is not in view and tried to scroll the element in to view. Its something to do with the function verifyEmailBatchListed which I am totally missing something.

```
var selenium = org.openqa.selenium
var time = JavaImporter(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var EC = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var io = JavaImporter(java.io)
var sleepThr = java.lang.Thread
var counterVal = WDS.vars.get("counter");
WDS.props.put("userNum", counterVal)
var filePath = WDS.vars.get('FileLocation')
var fileTimer = WDS.vars.get('timer')
var ENV = WDS.args[0]

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get(BaseURL)
login()
uploadFile()
clickSubmitBtn(submitButtonState,fileTimer)
verifyEmailBatchListed(emailBatchName,counterVal)
WDS.log.info("return value is "+value)
logout()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

function verifyEmailBatchListed(emailBatchName,counterVal) {
  WDS.props.put("emailBatchId_user" + counterVal, "")
  var round = 1
try{
  do {
    WDS.log.info("attempting to check for the email batch exist- " + round)
    WDS.browser.navigate().refresh()
    emailBatchlistItem = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + emailBatchName + "')]"), EC.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy, 120)
//    emailBatchlistItem.get(0).click()
    //        sleepThr.sleep(2000)
    if (undefined !== emailBatchlistItem && emailBatchlistItem.length != 0) {
      emailBatchlistItem.get(0).click()
      var emailBatchOverview = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-testid,\"email-dumps-overview-loading-false\")]"), EC.presenceOfElementLocated, 60)
      var checkStateCt = 0
      var EmailBatchUploadState
      var runCleanup = false
      try {
        do {            
          WDS.log.info("attempting to check for the state- " + checkStateCt)
          EmailBatchUploadState = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Email Batch Status')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'editField__target')]/p"), EC.presenceOfElementLocated, 60)
          var uploadState = EmailBatchUploadState.getText()
          WDS.log.info("The file batch '" + emailBatchName + "' is displayed in the email batches list and has status as - " + uploadState)
          if (uploadState == "COMPLETED") {
            runCleanup = true
            WDS.log.info("The email batch will be deleted")
            break;
          }
          else if (checkStateCt == 3) {
            WDS.log.info("The email batch will not be deleted")
            break;
          }
          else {
            sleepThr.sleep(2000)
            WDS.browser.navigate().refresh()
              emailBatchlistItem = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + emailBatchName + "')]"), EC.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy, 120)
              emailBatchlistItem.get(0).click()
          }
          checkStateCt++
        } while (checkStateCt <= 3)
      } catch (err) {
        WDS.log.error(err.message)
      }
      WDS.props.put("runCleanup", runCleanup)
      var emailBatchIdText = WDS.browser.findElement(selenium.By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + emailBatchName + "')]/../parent::li")).getAttribute("data-testid")
      var emailBatchId = emailBatchIdText.substring(emailBatchIdText.length() - 3);
      WDS.log.info("emailBatchId_user" + counterVal + " in WDS is " + emailBatchId);
      WDS.props.put("emailBatchId_user" + counterVal, emailBatchId)
      break;
    }
    else if (round == 4) {
      WDS.log.info("The file batch '" + emailBatchName + "' is not displayed in the email batches list")
      break;
    } else {
            sleepThr.sleep(2000)
    }
    round++
  } while (round <= 4)
  WDS.log.info("done checking for the email batch item in the list")
  } catch (err) {
    WDS.log.error(err.message)
  }
}

function logout() {
  WDS.log.info("pass 4")
  WDS.browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
  WDS.browser.executeScript("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight, 0)");
  //    WDS.browser.navigate().refresh()
  takeScreenshot('screenshot_beforeLogout')
  WDS.browser.findElement(selenium.By.xpath("//li[@data-selenium='/getting-started']")).click()
  var btnlist = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//div[@data-testid='subbar']//button"), EC.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy, 60)
  WDS.log.info("List of buttons are " + btnlist.length)
  for (var b = 0; b < btnlist.length; b++) {
    var btnTitle = btnlist.get(b).getAttribute("title")
    WDS.log.info("the btn attribute is " + btnTitle)
    if (btnTitle == "User Options") {

      btnlist.get(b).click();
      WDS.browser.findElement(selenium.By.cssSelector("button[data-testid='logout']")).click();
      var userNameField = waitByElement(selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Disclaimer')]"), EC.presenceOfElementLocated, 60)
      takeScreenshot('screenshot_loggedout')
    }
  }
}

function waitByElement(elementBy, conditionToExpect, timer) {
  try {
    var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, timer)
    element = wait.until(conditionToExpect(elementBy));
    return element;
  } catch (error) {
    WDS.log.error(error.message)
  }
}
```

Log trace

```
2022-04-11 10:56:19,333 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Load the application
2022-04-11 10:56:24,414 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Disclaimer screen displayed and clicking on Agree button
2022-04-11 10:56:25,851 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Enter the Credentials and click on Login
2022-04-11 10:56:29,917 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: Screenshot_Logging
2022-04-11 10:56:30,149 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Select Email Batches menu
2022-04-11 10:56:30,928 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Click on Upload Email link
2022-04-11 10:56:31,068 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Select an email file to Upload
2022-04-11 10:56:32,823 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Enter email batch details
2022-04-11 10:56:33,168 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Selecting the file portfolio type
2022-04-11 10:56:34,814 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Got list of SM portfolios: 30
2022-04-11 10:56:34,815 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Selecting suggested portfoilio item
2022-04-11 10:56:34,857 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Selecting portfolio name: test
2022-04-11 10:56:35,169 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_SelectSuggestedPortfolio
2022-04-11 10:56:35,964 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_beforeUpload
2022-04-11 10:56:36,242 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Click Upload submit button
2022-04-11 10:56:36,263 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_clickingUploadBtn
2022-04-11 10:56:37,567 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Waiting for loading image displayed
2022-04-11 10:56:37,657 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_AfterUpload
2022-04-11 10:56:38,301 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Waiting for loading image removed
2022-04-11 10:56:38,959 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_Noloadingimage
2022-04-11 10:56:39,452 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_UploadPercentage
2022-04-11 10:56:39,883 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: File started uploading
2022-04-11 10:56:39,917 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: current upload percent 0
2022-04-11 10:56:57,489 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Email batch upload processed succesfully in 17 secs
2022-04-11 10:56:57,490 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_UploadCompleted
2022-04-11 10:56:57,980 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: attempting to check for the email batch exist- 1
2022-04-11 10:57:02,859 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: attempting to check for the state- 0
2022-04-11 10:57:02,909 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: The file batch 'Uploaded from Jmeter_VLK' is displayed in the email batches list and has status as - COMPLETED
2022-04-11 10:57:02,910 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: The email batch will be deleted
2022-04-11 10:57:02,960 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: emailBatchId_user1 in WDS is 711
2022-04-11 10:57:02,961 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: done checking for the email batch item in the list
2022-04-11 10:57:02,968 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: pass 4
2022-04-11 10:57:03,004 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Taking screenshots for: screenshot_beforeLogout
2022-04-11 10:57:03,326 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: function __noSuchMethod__() { [native code] } is not a constructor function
2022-04-11 10:57:03,328 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined in <eval> at line number 291
2022-04-11 10:57:03,328 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Upload Email batches 2-1
2022-04-11 10:57:03,329 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Upload Email batches 2-1
2022-04-11 10:57:03,945 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2022-04-11 10:57:03,946 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: C:/Dev/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/Test data set/UploadTestEmailBatchesFile.csv
2022-04-11 10:57:03,948 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

[image: Logout button]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that your `btnlist` object doesn't have `length` property defined, you need to inspect your `waitByElement()` function and double [check the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893776/the-most-accurate-way-to-check-js-objects-type) of object it returns

If you want to get a comprehensive answer you're supposed to share the full code or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because your current piece is incomplete and doesn't tell the full story.

In the meantime you can check [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article for more details.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, Thanks. I even checked each and every step and I am able to resolve the issue. The culprit was with this line `var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)`. After removing the JavaImporter then it started working. But the question is in the whole script I used the support_ui.WebdriverWait many times and it just gave the issue only on the particular element. Also if I skip running the verifyEmailBatchListed function then also it worked. Not sure why that particular scenario it didn't work. As per your request I have added the waitByElement function also.