# Turning JSON strings into objects with methods

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an app that allows users to generate objects, and store them (in a MySQL table, as strings) for later use. The object could be :

```
function Obj() {
    this.label = "new object";
}

Obj.prototype.setLabel = function(newLabel) {
    this.label = newLabel;
}
```

If I use JSON.stringify on this object, I will only get the information on `Obj.label` (the stringified object would be a string like `{label: "new object"}`. If I store this string, and want to allow my user to retrieve the object later, the `setLabel` method will be lost.

So my question is: how can I re-instantiate the object, so that it keeps the properties stored thanks to JSON.stringify, but also gets back the different methods that should belong to its prototype. How would you do that ? I was thinking of something along "create a blank object" and "merge it with the stored one's properties", but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I applaud you @Cystack ! The notion of turning Javascript Objects (that are pure data attributes, no methods) is discussed here a lot. Yet this is the first question that I encounter that really focuses on objects, that are objects with methods. The `JSON.stringify` method normaly bears enough pitfalls (cyclic references, escaping/charsets, etc), so that most question focus on that and sadly very little I can find about this "automatic reinstanciating".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to use a "reviver" function when parsing the JSON string (and a "replacer" function or a `toJSON` function on your constructor's prototype when creating it). See [Section 15.12.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.12.2) and [15.12.3](http://es5.github.com/#x15.12.3) of the specification. If your environment doesn't yet support native JSON parsing, you can use [one of Crockford's parsers](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) (Crockford being the inventor of JSON), which also support "reviver" functions.

Here's a simple bespoke example that works with ES5-compliant browsers (or libraries that emulate ES5 behavior) ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/enutow), run in Chrome or Firefox or similar), but look after the example for a more generalized solution.

```
// Our constructor function
function Foo(val) {
  this.value = val;
}
Foo.prototype.nifty = "I'm the nifty inherited property.";
Foo.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return "/Foo(" + this.value + ")/";
};

// An object with a property, `foo`, referencing an instance
// created by that constructor function, and another `bar`
// which is just a string
var obj = {
  foo: new Foo(42),
  bar: "I'm bar"
};

// Use it
display("obj.foo.value = " + obj.foo.value);
display("obj.foo.nifty = " + obj.foo.nifty);
display("obj.bar = " + obj.bar);

// Stringify it with a replacer:
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);

// Show that
display("The string: " + str);

// Re-create it with use of a "reviver" function
var obj2 = JSON.parse(str, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "string" &&
      value.substring(0, 5) === "/Foo(" &&
      value.substr(-2) == ")/"
     ) {
    return new Foo(value.substring(5, value.length - 2));
  }
  return value;
});

// Use the result
display("obj2.foo.value = " + obj2.foo.value);
display("obj2.foo.nifty = " + obj2.foo.nifty);
display("obj2.bar = " + obj2.bar);
```

Note the `toJSON` on `Foo.prototype`, and the function we pass into `JSON.parse`.

The problem there, though, is that the reviver is tightly coupled to the `Foo` constructor. Instead, you can adopt a generic framework in your code, where any constructor function can support a `fromJSON` (or similar) function, and you can use just one generalized reviver.

Here's an example of a generalized reviver that looks for a `ctor` property and a `data` property, and calls `ctor.fromJSON` if found, passing in the full value it received ([live example](http://jsbin.com/anugeg)):

```
// A generic "smart reviver" function.
// Looks for object values with a `ctor` property and
// a `data` property. If it finds them, and finds a matching
// constructor that has a `fromJSON` property on it, it hands
// off to that `fromJSON` fuunction, passing in the value.
function Reviver(key, value) {
  var ctor;

  if (typeof value === "object" &&
      typeof value.ctor === "string" &&
      typeof value.data !== "undefined") {
    ctor = Reviver.constructors[value.ctor] || window[value.ctor];
    if (typeof ctor === "function" &&
        typeof ctor.fromJSON === "function") {
      return ctor.fromJSON(value);
    }
  }
  return value;
}
Reviver.constructors = {}; // A list of constructors the smart reviver should know about
```

To avoid having to repeat common logic in `toJSON` and `fromJSON` functions, you could have generic versions:

```
// A generic "toJSON" function that creates the data expected
// by Reviver.
// `ctorName`  The name of the constructor to use to revive it
// `obj`       The object being serialized
// `keys`      (Optional) Array of the properties to serialize,
//             if not given then all of the objects "own" properties
//             that don't have function values will be serialized.
//             (Note: If you list a property in `keys`, it will be serialized
//             regardless of whether it's an "own" property.)
// Returns:    The structure (which will then be turned into a string
//             as part of the JSON.stringify algorithm)
function Generic_toJSON(ctorName, obj, keys) {
  var data, index, key;

  if (!keys) {
    keys = Object.keys(obj); // Only "own" properties are included
  }

  data = {};
  for (index = 0; index < keys.length; ++index) {
    key = keys[index];
    data[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return {ctor: ctorName, data: data};
}

// A generic "fromJSON" function for use with Reviver: Just calls the
// constructor function with no arguments, then applies all of the
// key/value pairs from the raw data to the instance. Only useful for
// constructors that can be reasonably called without arguments!
// `ctor`      The constructor to call
// `data`      The data to apply
// Returns:    The object
function Generic_fromJSON(ctor, data) {
  var obj, name;

  obj = new ctor();
  for (name in data) {
    obj[name] = data[name];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The advantage here being that you defer to the implementation of a specific "type" (for lack of a better term) for how it serializes and deserializes. So you might have a "type" that just uses the generics:

```
// `Foo` is a constructor function that integrates with Reviver
// but doesn't need anything but the generic handling.
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.nifty = "I'm the nifty inherited property.";
Foo.prototype.spiffy = "I'm the spiffy inherited property.";
Foo.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return Generic_toJSON("Foo", this);
};
Foo.fromJSON = function(value) {
  return Generic_fromJSON(Foo, value.data);
};
Reviver.constructors.Foo = Foo;
```

...or one that, for whatever reason, has to do something more custom:

```
// `Bar` is a constructor function that integrates with Reviver
// but has its own custom JSON handling for whatever reason.
function Bar(value, count) {
  this.value = value;
  this.count = count;
}
Bar.prototype.nifty = "I'm the nifty inherited property.";
Bar.prototype.spiffy = "I'm the spiffy inherited property.";
Bar.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  // Bar's custom handling *only* serializes the `value` property
  // and the `spiffy` or `nifty` props if necessary.
  var rv = {
    ctor: "Bar",
    data: {
      value: this.value,
      count: this.count
    }
  };
  if (this.hasOwnProperty("nifty")) {
    rv.data.nifty = this.nifty;
  }
  if (this.hasOwnProperty("spiffy")) {
    rv.data.spiffy = this.spiffy;
  }
  return rv;
};
Bar.fromJSON = function(value) {
  // Again custom handling, for whatever reason Bar doesn't
  // want to serialize/deserialize properties it doesn't know
  // about.
  var d = value.data;
      b = new Bar(d.value, d.count);
  if (d.spiffy) {
    b.spiffy = d.spiffy;
  }
  if (d.nifty) {
    b.nifty = d.nifty;
  }
  return b;
};
Reviver.constructors.Bar = Bar;
```

And here's how we might test that `Foo` and `Bar` work as expected ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/anugeg)):

```
// An object with `foo` and `bar` properties:
var before = {
  foo: new Foo(),
  bar: new Bar("testing", 42)
};
before.foo.custom = "I'm a custom property";
before.foo.nifty = "Updated nifty";
before.bar.custom = "I'm a custom property"; // Won't get serialized!
before.bar.spiffy = "Updated spiffy";

// Use it
display("before.foo.nifty = " + before.foo.nifty);
display("before.foo.spiffy = " + before.foo.spiffy);
display("before.foo.custom = " + before.foo.custom + " (" + typeof before.foo.custom + ")");
display("before.bar.value = " + before.bar.value + " (" + typeof before.bar.value + ")");
display("before.bar.count = " + before.bar.count + " (" + typeof before.bar.count + ")");
display("before.bar.nifty = " + before.bar.nifty);
display("before.bar.spiffy = " + before.bar.spiffy);
display("before.bar.custom = " + before.bar.custom + " (" + typeof before.bar.custom + ")");

// Stringify it with a replacer:
var str = JSON.stringify(before);

// Show that
display("The string: " + str);

// Re-create it with use of a "reviver" function
var after = JSON.parse(str, Reviver);

// Use the result
display("after.foo.nifty = " + after.foo.nifty);
display("after.foo.spiffy = " + after.foo.spiffy);
display("after.foo.custom = " + after.foo.custom + " (" + typeof after.foo.custom + ")");
display("after.bar.value = " + after.bar.value + " (" + typeof after.bar.value + ")");
display("after.bar.count = " + after.bar.count + " (" + typeof after.bar.count + ")");
display("after.bar.nifty = " + after.bar.nifty);
display("after.bar.spiffy = " + after.bar.spiffy);
display("after.bar.custom = " + after.bar.custom + " (" + typeof after.bar.custom + ")");

display("(Note that after.bar.custom is undefined because <code>Bar</code> specifically leaves it out.)");
```

Comment: interesting suggestion, but this works only with your Foo "class". If you look at my Obj(), I cannot use this to revive the object, for the `.label`property will be lost.

Comment: see this based on your example : http://jsfiddle.net/cBBd4/ the nifty property is lost

Comment: @Cystack: Actually, I added a generalized reviver (and just replaced it with a better one). Re your fiddle: Sure, that's down to the `Foo` object's `toJSON` function, which needs to be sure to save appropriate properties (many objects will have properties that shouldn't be serialized). You can also do a generalized thing, as shown in my latest update.

Comment: I am thankful for the displayed ideas. The notion to re-instantiate an object, so that serialization process ends again in **objects that have methods** is something useful. Besides the classic problem of circular references and JSON.stringify it is a necessary thing to store away **real objects (=with methods)** (not just data). Anyway having to manualy cite the objects name seems not yet the most perfect solution. What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript) to get the constructor refernce automatically?

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed create an empty instance and then merge the instance with the data. I recommend using a library function for ease of use (like `jQuery.extend`).

You had some errors though (`function ... = function(...)`, and JSON requires keys to be surrounded by `"`).

http://jsfiddle.net/sc8NU/1/

```
var data = '{"label": "new object"}';  // JSON
var inst = new Obj;                    // empty instance
jQuery.extend(inst, JSON.parse(data)); // merge
```

Note that merging like this sets properties directly, so if `setLabel` is doing some checking stuff, this won't be done this way.

Comment: very good ! this is the closest to what I thought. Now the only downside is that I spent hours not to include jQuery for various reasons, I would hate myself to include it just for that ^^ I'll look into the .extend function's code though

Comment: @Cystack: There are numerous `extend` functions available in many libraries; you could also just lend one and copy it into your project. The underscore.js one is free of dependencies: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js.

Comment: @Cystack & pimvdb: The problem here is that it assumes that `Obj` *can* be called with no arguments, and as pimvdb points out, it bypasses the API of the type (which may be just fine, or not). In my view, you're much better off deferring those decisions to the type itself (which could, of course, just happily use `extend` if appropraite).

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, this means moving away from JSON;  you're now customizing it, and so  you take on all of the potential headaches that entails.  The idea of JSON is to include data only, not code, to avoid all of the security problems that you get when you allow code to be included.  Allowing code means that you have to use eval to run that code and eval is evil.

Comment: I don't want to put code in JSON, I'm the just mentioning the fact that it's not storing the methods in any way. But I am open to any solution !

Comment: *"So far as I know, this means moving away from JSON..."* Not really, reviver functions have been around for a long time.

Comment: I guess I did not understand the nature of the question.  A reviver function allows you to use an existing function (not one in the JSON) to do things to the data as it's read, including building an object and adding your own code.  This could mean that you could store property names that flag what functions should be added to the reconstituted object.  But it doesn't store code in the JSON.  Unless I'm missing something...if I am, please feel free to enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the setters of Obj :

```
Obj.createFromJSON = function(json){
   if(typeof json === "string") // if json is a string
      json = JSON.parse(json); // we convert it to an object
   var obj = new Obj(), setter; // we declare the object we will return
   for(var key in json){ // for all properties
      setter = "set"+key[0].toUpperCase()+key.substr(1); // we get the name of the setter for that property (e.g. : key=property => setter=setProperty
      // following the OP's comment, we check if the setter exists :
      if(setter in obj){
         obj[setter](json[key]); // we call the setter
      }
      else{ // if not, we set it directly
         obj[key] = json[key];
      }
   }
   return obj; // we finally return the instance
};
```

This requires your class to have setters for all its properties. 
This method is static, so you can use like this :

```
var instance = Obj.createFromJSON({"label":"MyLabel"});
var instance2 = Obj.createFromJSON('{"label":"MyLabel"}');
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution; perhaps in case `setXXX` is not available, just set it directly (since quite a number of properties may not need a separate setter function).

Answer (score 1):

From ECMAScript 6 onwards you can just do:

```
Object.assign(new Obj(), JSON.parse(rawJsonString))
```

**Note**: You create a new empty object of the defined type first and then override its properties with the parsed JSON. Not the other way around.

The methods define behaviour and contain no variable data. They are "stored" as your code. So you don't actually have to store them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use toString on the method.

Update:

Iterate over the methods in obj and store them as string, and then instantiate them with new Function.

```
storedFunc = Obj.prototype.setLabel.toString();
Obj2.prototype['setLabel'] = new Function("return (" + storedFunc + ")")();
```

Comment: what do you mean ? so that I store the method as a string in the object ? that defeats the purpose of the prototype, no ?

Comment: not necessarily IN the object, in your DB, just add a table for methods and which object they belong to, send back normal json for the object and then the method strings and add them to the objects..

Comment: Since the OP asked about the objects to have methods, when it comes to JSON, then I think the idea to use the `replacer` to store the methods in a String (which maybe should be escaped and or base64 to not brake JSON notation) and to revive the methods later. The suggestion may not be considered (nice, i.e. to have methods stored in a DB) but I think it links to the OP and the answer defnitively enriches the solution space, @j-a thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own stringify method that stores functions as properties by converting them to strings using the toString method.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is [prototype based programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) which is classless language where object orientation achieved by process of cloning existing objects that serve as prototypes.

Serializing JSON would be considering any methods, for instance if you have an object

```
var x = {
    a: 4
    getText: function() {
       return x.a;
    }
};
```

You will get just `{ a:4 }` where `getText` method is skipped by the serializer.

I ran into this same trouble a year back and I had to maintain a separate helper class for each of my domain object and used [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) it to my **deserialized** object when need, just more like having **methods to a base class for the domain objects**.