# ask for a method in javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, methods

i have one question, i have this class in javascript:

```
//FactVal
UTIL.Classes.FactVal = function(entity, attribute, value) {
    this.entity = entity;
    this.attribute = attribute;
    this.value = value;
}

UTIL.Classes.FactVal.prototype.setEntity = function(entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
}
```

When im serializing a json string to an object of this type, i want to ask if exists the setEntity method, i have this json:

```
"FactVal": {
              "entity": {
               "string": "blabla"
              }
}
```

When i read "entity" i want to know if exists a method "setEntity" in the FactVal class, i think i have to do this: the value of 'i' is "FactVal" and the value of 'j' is "entity".

```
if(UTIL.Classes[i].("set" + j[0].toUpperCase() + j.substring(1,j.length)))
```

and dont work, how can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, you want `[]` and you need to look at the `prototype` property of the constructor function, not the constructor function itself:

```
if(UTIL.Classes[i].prototype["set" + j.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + j.substring(1,j.length)])
```

(I also replaced your `j[0]` with `j.charAt(0)`, not all JavaScript engines in the wild support indexing into strings like that yet.)

Or better:

```
if(typeof UTIL.Classes[i].prototype["set" + j.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + j.substring(1,j.length)] === "function")
```

That works because you can access the property of an object either via the familiar dotted notation with a literal:

```
x = obj.foo;
```

...or via bracketed notation with a string:

```
x = obj["foo"];
// or
s = "foo";
x = obj[s];
// or
p1 = "f";
p2 = "o";
x = obj[p1 + p2 + p2];
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
FactVal.setEntity
```

You have to look at the prototype, just like you did when setting the property originally:

```
Factval.prototype.setEntity
```

also, you need to use bracket notation istead of parenthesis (like you did with the `[i]`):

```
if( UTIL.Classes[i].prototype["set" + j[0].toUpperCase() + j.substring(1,j.length)] )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use indexer notation:

```
if (typeof URIL.Classes[i]["set" + (...)] === "function")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like this :

[Turning JSON strings into objects with methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111446/turning-json-strings-into-objects-with-methods/8111606#8111606)

However, that line :

```
if(UTIL.Classes[i].("set" + j[0].toUpperCase() + j.substring(1,j.length)))
```

Should be replaced with :

```
if(typeof UTIL.Classes[i]["set" + j[0].toUpperCase() + j.substr(1)] === "function")
```

NOTE : j.substr(1) is equivalent to j.substring(1,j.length)