# typescript JSON.stringify loose type and function

Tags: json, typescript

I know JSON.stringify doesn't stringify function, but what's the good practice because hydration is really exhausting. I don't want to create a new object. Any idea ?

```
class pers {
    name = "";
    last = "";

    constructor(name: string, last: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.last = last;
    }

    alo() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

let pa = new pers("ben", "troq");
let s = JSON.stringify(pa);
let o = <pers>JSON.parse(s);
let pb = new pers("", "");

pb = o;
pb.alo();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111446/turning-json-strings-into-objects-with-methods

Comment: Unrelated, but do yourself a favour and make the code consistent (put spaces around `=` everywhere, or do it nowhere if that makes you happier) and write out names (class `person`, with attributes `firstname` and `lastname` for example, instead of pers, name, last). What would `pa`, `s`, `o` and `pb` even stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let o = <pers>JSON.parse(s);
```

I belive you think this is a type-cast, but it is *not*. This is a [type-*assertion*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html), which does not imply runtime support. Basically, you are only telling the compiler to *believe* `o` is of type `pers`, but that is not true at *runtime*:

```
o instanceof pers; // false
```

You will either need to manually create the object instance using your JSON as Nitzan [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968709/2788872), or create a routine that reads some metadata information to automatically create the correct instances with the corresponding properties.

---

For the latter approach, I would recommend trying out [TypedJSON](https://github.com/JohnWhiteTB/TypedJSON), which I created to provide an elegant and widely adaptable solution to this exact problem:

```
@JsonObject
class pers {
    @JsonMember name = "";
    @JsonMember last = "";

    constructor(name?: string, last?: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.last = last;
    }

    alo() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

```js
let o = TypedJSON.parse(s, pers);
o instanceof pers; // true
o.alo(); // "ben"
```

Note the parameterless constructor, that is required (in most similar systems, as well).

This solution builds on [ReflectDecorators](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators), but it's not required (however, without it you will need to manually specify the constructor function of properties: `@JsonMember({ type: String }) ...` for example).

Answer (score 1):

How about separating the data from the functionality?

```
interface PersData {
    name: string;
    last: string;
}

class pers {
    private data: PersData;

    constructor(data: PersData | string) {
        this.data = typeof data === "string" ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
    }

    alo() {
        alert(this.data.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
let o  = <pers>JSON.parse(s);
let pb = new pers("", "");

pb = o;
pb.alo();
```

with:

```
let o  = JSON.parse(s);
let pb = Object.create(pers.prototype);
Object.assign(pb, o);

pb.alo();
```

It should work. `Object.create` (ES5.1) creates an object whose linked prototype is the one from the `pers` class but without running the `pers` constructor. Then `Object.assign` (ES6) copies the properties from the object unserialized from JSON to the object referenced by `pb`. Because the prototype was correctly set by `Object.create` calling the methods will work.

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just putting code in here? What is the key thing that makes your answer work? I ask because with an explanation others can learn from your answer and apply that to other questions. That is what stackoverflow is about --- not blindly copying & pasting some code.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the snippet was self-evident. Edited and added an explanation.