# How to get an object name?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet

```
function receiver(callback)
{
    console.log( callback );
}

function callback(){}

receiver( new callback() );

OUTPUT: callback {}
```

is there a method or way to get 'callback' out of callback parameter? I like to get an object's name.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> function callback(){}
undefined
> a = new callback();
[object Object]
> a.constructor.name
callback>
```

But, it won't work for any anonymous functions (everything is in the title):

```
> callback = function(){};
function () {}
> c = new callback();
[object Object]
> c.constructor.name
(empty string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function receiver(callback){
    console.log(callback.constructor.name);
}

function callback(){}

receiver(new callback());
```

Have a look at: [javascript introspection in 90 seconds](http://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2010/06/javascript-introspection-in-90-seconds/)