# Requesting a particular JSON dictionary from a JSON stream

Tags: json, parsing, rest, dictionary, webrequest

This is kind of an abstract question, so forgive me if it doesn't fit here. I'm wondering if there's a standard way to query a JSON stream for a particular sub-dictionary, instead of having the stream return all of its contents at once. I'm hoping I could use parameters in the URL to do this, but I'm not sure if there's a standardized methodology for making such queries.

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: JSON stream? Are you talking about getting the request stream and detecting if an object hash is present while you are moving through the input stream? Which server-side? This isn't possible client-side to do "streams" that I know of.

Comment: Yeah I mean, I guess it's a little bit of a naive question. Stream maybe isn't the right word. I was hoping there was a standardized query format to get a dictionary in an array of JSON dictionaries, filtered by a certain parameter, through some URL schema.

Comment: Now, I'm very confused. Which server-side technology are you referring to? Otherwise, JavaScript on the client does not have a "query" language for this, at least not directly as the language itself. JavaScript has objects (functions or hashes or arrays) or numerics or booleans or strings. See here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript  to detect "type".