# Preserve function name uglify mangle

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface, uglifyjs

We're linking together Javascript and AS3. For this to work AS3 needs to know the function names of the Javascript methods.

We're using Uglify to optimize our Javascript code. Now I don't want these specific functions to be mangled. All other functions can be mangled just fine. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: Sometimes people lose more time writing a question here than searching for a solution

Comment: How could I've missed that o.O ... oh well, thanks guys!

Comment: @SharpEdge I actually searched for 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use this parameter:
--reserved-names “myFunction”

Possible duplicate:[Prevent uglifyjs from renaming certain functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807263/prevent-uglifyjs-from-renaming-certain-functions)

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, flag it up as one rather than answering with the duplicate answer.

Comment: Good to know! Next time....