# Determine name of a JavaScript object instance's class

Tags: javascript, reflection, prototype-programming

Imagine a JavaScript "class" `Foo`:

```
var Foo = function()
{
};
```

And an instance of that class:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

Can I obtain the string `Foo` directly from the instance `foo`, or is `Foo` just a transitive variable that cannot be associated with the instance `foo` after instantiation?

---

**EDIT 1** [SLaks suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994249/24874) using `foo.constructor`. This gives:

```
function ()
{
}
```

This approach works if the function is defined in the form:

```
function Foo()
{}
```

...but this might not always be the case.

---

**EDIT 2** Trying [skizeey's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994255/24874) doesn't work either. It is essentially a more complete attempt as Slack's method, but yields an empty string: `""`

---

**EDIT 3** I wonder whether this is actually possible somehow.  Notice the following transcript from Chrome's JavaScript console:

```
> var Foo = function() {}
undefined
> var foo = new Foo();
undefined
> foo
Foo
```

In the last line, Chrome clearly knows that the object is of type `Foo`. However this may just be a Chrome thing, and not standard JavaScript or even inaccessible from the language itself.

Comment: Do you really need the string `"Foo"`? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to leverage a convention in my code. I'm using RequireJS and knowing this name would mean I'd know what module the class was defined in, so I could load it again upon resaturating data from local storage.

Comment: If you control the constructors in the modules being required, you may just need to write the names in. If you don't, then are you hoping to re-associate the data with its original prototype chain? Or is it merely to know which modules to load?

Comment: @user1689607, both in a sense. By reloading the correct module, I'll have access to an instance of the class where the name matches the module. Unless someone can find a way to do this, I'll even have to add my own property to each module that fits this pattern, or change the way I declare my constructors.

Comment: Generally I'd suggest using named functions for constructors, if for nothing else, it helps in debugging. You can keep using function expressions, but use named expressions. `var Foo = function Foo() {...};` Though I'd prefer standard declarations. `function Foo(){...}`

Comment: @user1689607, see my third edit. Chrome knows the name of the function even without using named function expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea how Chrome does that but I assume it's some custom behavior, because it certainly isn't part of the language spec. If you make a `Foo` object, but change its prototype so that there's no longer any connection between the object and the original constructor, it still gives you `"Foo"`. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6gCQ/

Comment: @user1689607, if you want to put your comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to throw my support behind @MarkReed's answer. Pretty much cuts to the heart of the issue, and I'm just feeling a little too lazy right now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With named function:

```
> var Foo = function Foo(){};
> undefined
> var foo = new Foo();
> undefined
> foo.constructor.name
> "Foo"
```

With unnamed function:

```
> var Foo = function (){};
> undefined
> var foo = new Foo();
> undefined
> foo.constructor.name
> ""
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve what you want without modifying the module code.

When you define a function like

```
var Foo = function() {...}
```

The function - and any object created using it as a constructor - has no knowledge of the name `Foo`.  You might as well do `var x = 0` and then attempt to get the value `0` to tell you about the name `x`.

Comment: Take a look at my third edit. Somehow Chrome knows the name of the class, even though it was not from a named function expression. I want to know whether this is something that's part of the standard, or just a privilege that Chrome is flaunting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Foo` function by from `foo.constructor`.
However, you cannot associate that function instance with the name of the variable you assign it to.

Comment: Unless you overwrite the constructor property.

Answer (score 0):

From [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript):

```
var getName = function(object) { 
  var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
  var results = (funcNameRegex).exec(object.constructor.toString());
  return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
```

You're essentially just grabbing the entire constructor as a string, and then extracting its name.

One caveat though: like what clentfort said on a comment to SLaks' answer, there's no one stopping anyone from overwriting an object's constructor property.

Another caveat: you are also going to have to explicitly name your function, too.

Comment: it still doesn't work. Try it with the code sample from my question. It just returns an empty string.