# Angular Unit Testing: Using Generics to Create Component

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a generic wrapper around `TestBed.createComponent`, which takes a type argument and creates the component for that type. However, the `TestBed.createComponent` function takes an argument of type `Type<T>`. I'm unable to create a `Type<T>` from the passed in generic T argument.

```js
export function createTestHarness<T>(): TestHarness<T> {
  let component: T;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<T>;

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent<T>(**PROBLEM AREA**);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  return new TestHarness<T>(component, fixture);
}
```

Is there a way to derive a `Type<T>` from the type passed in?

Answer (score 5):

One option you have is to use the `Type<T>` as a parameter to your function:

```js
function createTestHarness<T>(type: Type<T>): TestHarness<T> {
  let component: T;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<T>;

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent<T>(type);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  return new TestHarness<T>(component, fixture);
}
```

With the following usage:

```js
const harness = createTestHarness(TestComponent);
```

Which will return a `TestHarness<TestComponent>`.

Answer (score 0):

Generics only exists at compile time and not at runtime. So you can not derive the type of T.

[Get type of generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215899/get-type-of-generic-parameter)