# Typescript: get type of generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm new to Typescript (come from C#) and i'm struggeling with the "special" generic implementation.

Here is my code:

```
function createValue<TValue extends string | boolean>(): TValue[]
{
    let result = new Array<TValue>();

    if (typeof TValue === "string") // error 'TValue' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
    {
        result[0] = "abc" as TValue;
    }
    else
    {
        result[0] = false as TValue;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(createValue<boolean>());
```

How did i get the type?

I'm allready tried pretty ugly solutions to create a value, but this also don't behave as expected.

```
let value : TValue = new Array<TValue>(1)[0];
let type = typeof value; // undefined
```

There exists several solutions for object types but i didn't get it for primitives.

Could you give me any help?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get type of generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215899/get-type-of-generic-parameter)

Comment: Unfortunaly not, because the best solution requires an existing, defined value - which i didn't have. Is there a solution to dynamic create a defined primitive?

Comment: I'm afraid not, this is what they explained in the linked answer : "Generics are a TypeScript concept that helps check the correctness of your code but doesn't exist in the compiled output. So the short answer is no, it's not possible."

Comment: types do not exist at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Types did not exists at runtime i end up with a solution like this:

```
enum Types
{
    string,
    boolean,
    number
}

function getType<TValue extends Types.string | Types.boolean>(t: TValue): Array<TValue extends Types.string ? string : boolean>
{
    if (<Types>t == Types.string)
    {
        let arr = new Array<string>();
        arr[0] = "abcd";
        return arr as Array<TValue extends Types.string ? string : boolean>;       
    }

    let arr = new Array<boolean>();
    arr[0] = false;
    return arr as Array<TValue extends Types.string ? string : boolean>;     
}

console.log(getType(Types.boolean));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in using the TypeScript type at runtime. 
TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, therefore your execution does not see the the type `TValue` at all.

The `typeof` operator is used to reuse type information at other places but not at runtime. E.g.

```
function test(arg: string): boolean;

function test2(func1: typeof test): boolean;
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, you need to give a string argument that specifies your operation.

```
function createValue(type: 'string' | 'boolean') {
    let result = new Array();

    if (type === "string") 
    {
        result[0] = "abc";
    }
    else
    {
        result[0] = false;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(createValue('boolean'));
```

TypeScript should be able to infer your types from there. If not, you could look into [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).

Comment: Conditional Types was the key for me, thanks for your explanation.