# Current method on typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I´m developing an `ionic2` application, and I want to print my current method name on console.

Example:

```
 constructor(private myclass: Myclass) {
   console.log(<methodname>);
   // in this case should be constructor
 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Here's a javascript way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114150/get-the-class-function-name-within-itself

Comment: There will only ever be a JavaScript way.