# Getting Class Name in TypeScript inside an export function from a special parameter

Tags: typescript

How my structure looks like ?

```
namespace DataProviders
{
     export function SomeExportFunction<T>(myConstructor: { new (): T; MappingOptions?: any; }): T[]
    {
        //getting "SomeClass" as a string from "someModuleOrNameSpace.SomeClass" which should be somewhere in "myConstructor"(parameter)
    }
}
```

How to use ?
    `this.Something=SomeNamespace.SomeExportFunction(someModuleOrNameSpace.SomeClass);`

I tried `myConstructor.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];` this will return `Function`, bit I need `SomeClass`.

Based on this post [Get an object's class name at runtime in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime-in-typescript).

So how can I get the class name of `myConstructor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same as in the thread you linked to, with one exception which is that you want the name from the class instead of the instance.
So this:

```
myConstructor.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];
```

Should be:

```
myConstructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];
```

If `myConstructor` was an instance then `myConstructor.constructor` would have been the class.  In your case this step is reduandent.