# How can I return a new Type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a d.ts file for a lib which provide a static method `extend` to create new type(sub type):

```
const SubType = SimpleLib.extend(proto);
const instance = new SubType();
```

How to write the d.ts file?

Comment: Visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic, something like:

```
declare type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function extend<T extends Constructor>(ConstructorToExtend: T) => T;
```