# Typescript: proper constructor name when used class decorator (target to ES5+Lib.ES2015)

Tags: typescript

Here is test code:

```
class TBaseClass {}

interface Newable<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

function Decorate() {
    return function <T extends Newable<TBaseClass>>(constructor: T): any {
        // extend constructor
        return class extends constructor {
            protected _extraField: string = '-'
        }; 
    }
}

@Decorate()
class Test {}

@Decorate()
class ExtTest extends Test {}

alert(ExtTest.name) // returns "class_1", how to get "ExtTest"?
```

In case if code transpilied to JS(ES2015), result will be "**ExtTest**".

But if project targeted to ES5 with ES2015 lib, result will be "class_1".

That can be tested in [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).
Is it normal behavior?

Any suggestions how to correctly solve that issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that gets transpiled, minified, or otherwise modified during a build step shouldn't rely on [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Function_names_in_classes) to be anything predictable at runtime.  That, of course, includes TypeScript code.

You can try explicitly setting the `name` property of the class constructor if you care about it, but it's [not straightforward](http://2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html#changing-the-names-of-functions), and in some runtime environments it might even be completely prevented.  Also, TypeScript will [not let you](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12065) depending on your target version of JS.

Why do you need this?  For debugging?  Is there some third-party tool that cares about the `name` property of the constructor?  If at all possible I'd suggest just using your own property and setting it explicitly:

```
@Decorate()
class Test {
  static readonly className: string = "Test"
}

@Decorate()
class ExtTest extends Test {
  static readonly className: string = "ExtTest"
}    

alert(ExtTest.className) // returns "ExtTest"
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I have method that accepts array of classes (not objects). And i need correctly identify class names. may be reflect-metadata library will help..

Comment: But *why* do you need to correctly identify class names?  As I said, you can't rely on the name being what you expect.  Unless you are going to `eval()` something, I don't understand why you need runtime access to the name.  If you present your use case, maybe someone can suggest a more reliable solution.

Comment: http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4#1-why-we-need-reflection-in-javascript_1

Comment: Have you tried using it?  I don't think it gives you what you want.  The `design:type` property of a class object is the constructor function itself, not its name.

Comment: Looks like you right :)
The only way is set name as string which will not be changed by minifier.
May be in some future TS compiler will automatically add such useful information in generated JS code.

Comment: By the way, i found almost same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613524/get-an-objects-class-name-at-runtime-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

```
function Decorate() {
           return function <T extends Newable<TBaseClass>>(constructor: T): any {
           const instance = new constructor();
           console.log(instance.constructor.name) // class name
           }
       }
       
       @Decorate()
       class Test {
        name:"abc"
       }
      
       @Decorate()
       class ExtTest {
         name:"efg"
       }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).