# How to change an object's class name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance

I would like to know, is there a way to:

- change an object's class name? or
- set class name to an anonymous class? or
- dinamically generate the class name?

For example, I have a decorator:

```js
export const decor = <T extends Constructable>(Clazz: T): T => {
    return class extends Clazz {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            //...
        }
    };
};
```

It's a class decorator. All it does it's just add some extra logic to the object. But here's a problem. For the debugging I want to know the name of class. But if I use this decorator, the class name is look like `class_1`.

I tried to solve it with this attempts:

*Dinamically generate the class name*:

```js
return class [`${Clazz.name}_dec`] extends Clazz // compilation error
```

*Change an object's class name*:

```js
const tmp = class extends Clazz {...}
tmp.name = `${Clazz.name}_dec`; // this doesn't change anything
return tmp;
```

And none of them had worked.

So, is there a way to set class name in decorator or change it somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: proper constructor name when used class decorator (target to ES5+Lib.ES2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833911/typescript-proper-constructor-name-when-used-class-decorator-target-to-es5lib)

Comment: No. I have to set `name` field. I can't just create some other field